# pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have 3 CSV files. Each has the first column as the (string) names of people, while all the other columns in each dataframe are attributes of that person.

How can I "join" together all three CSV documents to create a single CSV with each row having all the attributes for each unique value of the person's string name?

The `join()` function in pandas specifies that I need a multiindex, but I'm confused about what a hierarchical indexing scheme has to do with making a join based on a single index.

Comment: You don't need a multiindex.  It states in the join docs that of you don't have a multiindex when passing multiple columns to join on then it will handle that.

Comment: In my trials, `df1.join([df2, df3], on=[df2_col1, df3_col1])` didn't work.

Comment: You need to chain them together like in the answer given.  Merge df1 and df2 then merge the result with df3

Comment: Creating an empty data fram and appending columns to it is the simplest solution I found after getting errors from solutions provided below:
https://onecompiler.com/python/3zhtqjrut
Source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-and-append-rows-columns-to-it-in-pandas/?ref=gcse

Answer (score 645, accepted):

[Zero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671390/366309) is basically a `reduce` operation.  If I had more than a handful of dataframes, I'd put them in a list like this (generated via list comprehensions or loops or whatnot):

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, ..., dfN]
```

Assuming they have a common column, like `name` in your example, I'd do the following:

```
import functools as ft
df_final = ft.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='name'), dfs)
```

That way, your code should work with whatever number of dataframes you want to merge.

Comment: I just tried using this and it failed because `reduce` was replaced with [`functools.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/nameerror-name-reduce-is-not-defined-in-python) So `import functools functools.reduce(.......)`

Comment: How will this solution work if I the names of the fields to join are different? For example, in three data frames I could have `name1`, `name2` and `name3` respectively.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that we have `n-1` calls to the merge function? I guess in this case where the number of dataframes is small it doesn't matter, but I wonder if there's a more scalable solution.

Comment: This didn't quite work for my `df`s with column multi indexes (it was injecting the 'on' as a column which worked for the first merge, but subsequent merges failed), instead I got it to work with: `df = reduce(lambda  left, right: left.join(right, how='outer', on='Date'), dfs)`

Comment: +1 to ps0604. what if the join columns are different, does this work? should we go with pd.merge incase the join columns are different? thanks

Comment: Thanks! What if `df0,df1` have same columns to merge on and `df0,df2` have same columns to merge on?

Comment: Thanks! This answer preserves the columns, other than the one mentioned in `on`, which is absolutely correct. `concat` wouldn't do it.

Comment: What if they have no same column, but they only have same default column at the beginning of the dataframe? How to deal with this?

Answer (score 175):

You could try this if you have 3 dataframes

```
# Merge multiple dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['c', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 15, 49],
    ['b', 4, 36],
    ['c', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr31', 'attr32'])

pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name'),df3,on='name')
```

alternatively, as mentioned by cwharland

```
df1.merge(df2,on='name').merge(df3,on='name')
```

Comment: For cleaner looks you can chain them

    `df1.merge(df2,on='name').merge(df3,on='name')`

Comment: How will this solution work if I the names of the fields to join are different? For example, in three data frames I could have `name1`, `name2` and `name3` respectively

Comment: @ps0604 `df1.merge(df2,left_on='name1', right_on='name2').merge(df3,left_on='name1', right_on='name3').drop(columns=['name2', 'name3']).rename(columns={'name1':'name'})`

Comment: and further, how to do this using the index. Doesn't seem to work if 'name' is the index and not a column name.

Answer (score 162):

## This is an ideal situation for the `join` method

The `join` method is built exactly for these types of situations. You can join any number of DataFrames together with it. The calling DataFrame joins with the index of the collection of passed DataFrames. To work with multiple DataFrames, you must put the joining columns in the index.

The code would look something like this:

```
filenames = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4',....]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=index_col) for filename in filenames)]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])
```

With @zero's data, you could do this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['c', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 15, 49],
    ['b', 4, 36],
    ['c', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr31', 'attr32'])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [df.set_index('name') for df in dfs]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])

     attr11 attr12 attr21 attr22 attr31 attr32
name                                          
a         5      9      5     19     15     49
b         4     61     14     16      4     36
c        24      9      4      9     14      9
```

Comment: Joining all of the dfs to an empty dataframe also works: `pd.DataFrame().join(dfs, how="outer")`. This can be cleaner in some situations.

Comment: This is decent advice and has now been incorporated into [pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/4909087) (see the section on merging multiple dataframes). It's worth noting that if your join keys are unique, using `pd.concat` will result in simpler syntax: `pd.concat([df.set_index('name') for df in dfs], axis=1, join='inner').reset_index()`. `concat` is also more versatile when dealing with duplicate column names across multiple dfs (`join` isn't as good at this) although you can only perform inner or outer joins with it.

Comment: `dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])` should be edited to `dfs[0].join(dfs[1:], sort=False)`  because otherwise a `FutureWarning` will pop up. Thanks for the nice example.

Comment: I get an error on trying that: `ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values`, although, by inspection of the individual dataframes in the list, they don't seem to have overlapping values.

Answer (score 41):

In `python` 3.6.3 with `pandas` 0.22.0 you can also use `concat` as long as you set as index the columns you want to use for the joining:

```
pd.concat(
    objs=(iDF.set_index('name') for iDF in (df1, df2, df3)),
    axis=1, 
    join='inner'
).reset_index()
```

where `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` are defined as in [John Galt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671390/366309):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12']
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['b', 14, 16],
    ['c', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22']
)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 15, 49],
    ['b', 4, 36],
    ['c', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr31', 'attr32']
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the fastest.

Comment: What if dataframe shapes are different?

Comment: @AbhilashRamteke If you mean that they have different number or rows (so the `name` column is not the same in all data frames) then `join='outer'` should preserve them all, but you will have missing values. No issues with respect to different column sets, as long as they all share the `name` column, which is used for index

Answer (score 21):

This can also be done as follows for a list of dataframes `df_list`:

```
df = df_list[0]
for df_ in df_list[1:]:
    df = df.merge(df_, on='join_col_name')
```

or if the dataframes are in a generator object (e.g. to reduce memory consumption):

```
df = next(df_list)
for df_ in df_list:
    df = df.merge(df_, on='join_col_name')
```

Answer (score 12):

**Simple Solution:**

If the column names are similar:

```
 df1.merge(df2,on='col_name').merge(df3,on='col_name')
```

If the column names are different:

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on='col_name1', right_on='col_name2').merge(df3,left_on='col_name1', right_on='col_name3').drop(columns=['col_name2', 'col_name3']).rename(columns={'col_name1':'col_name'})
```

Answer (score 8):

One does not need a multiindex to perform [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) operations.
One just need to set correctly the index column on which to perform the join operations (which command `df.set_index('Name')` for example)

The `join` operation is by default performed on index.
In your case, you just have to specify that the `Name` column corresponds to your index.
Below is an example

A [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) may be useful.

```
# Simple example where dataframes index are the name on which to perform
# the join operations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
name = ['Sophia' ,'Emma' ,'Isabella' ,'Olivia' ,'Ava' ,'Emily' ,'Abigail' ,'Mia']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['A','B','C'], index=name)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), columns=['D'],         index=name)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), columns=['E','F'],     index=name)
df = df1.join(df2)
df = df.join(df3)

# If you have a 'Name' column that is not the index of your dataframe,
# one can set this column to be the index
# 1) Create a column 'Name' based on the previous index
df1['Name'] = df1.index
# 1) Select the index from column 'Name'
df1 = df1.set_index('Name')

# If indexes are different, one may have to play with parameter how
gf1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['A','B','C'], index=range(8))
gf2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), columns=['D'], index=range(2,10))
gf3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), columns=['E','F'], index=range(4,12))

gf = gf1.join(gf2, how='outer')
gf = gf.join(gf3, how='outer')
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a method to merge a dictionary of data frames while keeping the column names in sync with the dictionary. Also it fills in missing values if needed:

## This is the function to merge a dict of data frames

```
def MergeDfDict(dfDict, onCols, how='outer', naFill=None):
  keys = dfDict.keys()
  for i in range(len(keys)):
    key = keys[i]
    df0 = dfDict[key]
    cols = list(df0.columns)
    valueCols = list(filter(lambda x: x not in (onCols), cols))
    df0 = df0[onCols + valueCols]
    df0.columns = onCols + [(s + '_' + key) for s in valueCols] 

    if (i == 0):
      outDf = df0
    else:
      outDf = pd.merge(outDf, df0, how=how, on=onCols)   

  if (naFill != None):
    outDf = outDf.fillna(naFill)

  return(outDf)
```

## OK, lets generates data and test this:

```
def GenDf(size):
  df = pd.DataFrame({'categ1':np.random.choice(a=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size=size, replace=True),
                      'categ2':np.random.choice(a=['A', 'B'], size=size, replace=True), 
                      'col1':np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=size), 
                      'col2':np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=size)
                      })
  df = df.sort_values(['categ2', 'categ1', 'col1', 'col2'])
  return(df)


size = 5
dfDict = {'US':GenDf(size), 'IN':GenDf(size), 'GER':GenDf(size)}   
MergeDfDict(dfDict=dfDict, onCols=['categ1', 'categ2'], how='outer', naFill=0)
```

Comment: Nice method.  See correction below in  MergeDfDict:
  keys = dfDict.keys(); 
  i = 0; 
  for key in keys:

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution from the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (that I don't see here),

**using the `.append`**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
   A  B
0  5  6
1  7  8
>>> df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

The `ignore_index=True` is used to ignore the index of the appended dataframe, replacing it with the next index available in the source one.

If there are different column names, `Nan` will be introduced.

Comment: it's semantic, for someone using the word "join" to say putting together the two dataframe. (not necessarely as the SQL join operation)

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked the accepted answer to perform the operation for multiple dataframes on different `suffix` parameters using `reduce` and i guess it can be extended to different `on` parameters as well.

```
from functools import reduce 

dfs_with_suffixes = [(df2,suffix2), (df3,suffix3), 
                     (df4,suffix4)]

merge_one = lambda x,y,sfx:pd.merge(x,y,on=['col1','col2'..], suffixes=sfx)

merged = reduce(lambda left,right:merge_one(left,*right), dfs_with_suffixes, df1)
```

Comment: Tweaked approach is great; however, a small fix must be added to avoid *ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*, a left suffices as empty string `""`. The final merge function could be as follow: `merge_one = lambda x,y,sfx:pd.merge(x,y,on=['col1','col2'..], suffixes=('', sfx))  # Left gets no suffix, right gets something identifiable`

Answer (score 1):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12']
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 19],
    ['d', 14, 16]]

),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22']
)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 15, 49],
    ['c', 4, 36],
    ['d', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr31', 'attr32']
)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 15, 49],
    ['c', 4, 36],
    ['c', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr41', 'attr42']
)
```

## Three ways to join list dataframe

1. `pandas.concat`

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [df.set_index('name') for df in dfs]
# cant not run if index not unique 
dfs = pd.concat(dfs, join='outer', axis = 1)
```

2. `functools.reduce`

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
# still run with index not unique 
import functools as ft
df_final = ft.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='name', how = 'outer'), dfs)
```

3. `join`

```py
# cant not run if index not unique 
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [df.set_index('name') for df in dfs]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:], how = 'outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

Joining together all three can be done using `.join()` function.

You have three DataFrames lets say
`df1, df2, df3`.
To join these into one DataFrame you can:

```
df = df1.join(df2).join(df3)
```

This is the simplest way I found to do this task.