# Delete rows not present in all DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

## Background

There is 5 DataFrames, I will call them `b1, b2, b3, b4, b5`.

They have data structure which consists of the columns `['Date', 'Value']`

I got the data from 2014 to 2015.

## Problem

Every DataFrame has different date counting system. So, I want to get rid of the rows in the DataFrames which have non-matching dates.

How can I do that?

## What I have tried

So, I will delete all the data if `Date` of the data is not included in all DataFrames: `b1, b2, b3, b4, b5`

This works for the first time

```
for i in range(len(b2.index)):
    k = 0
    for j in range(len(b1.index)):
        if b2['Date'][i] == b1['Date'][j]:
            k = k+1
        else:
            k = k
    if k == 1:
        pass
    if k == 0:
        b2 = b2.drop([i])
```

But, after that I excute this code one more time after I did that, there would be some error like this:

> KeyError    Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   2k = 0
>   3for j in range(len(b2.index)):
>   ----> 4    if b1['Date'][i] == b2['Date'][j]:
>   5   k = k+1
>   6    else:
>
> C:\Users\cms\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in **getitem**(self, key)
>      519def **getitem**(self, key):
>      520    try:
>   --> 521   result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>      522 
>      523   if not np.isscalar(result):
>
> C:\Users\cms\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
>     1593 
>     1594    try:
>   -> 1595   return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
>     1596    except KeyError as e1:
>     1597   if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3113)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2844)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3704)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:7224)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:7162)()
>
> KeyError: 28L

What I want to do is

```
mlist = (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)
for q in mlist:
    for r in mlist:
        for i in range(len(q.index)):
            k = 0
            for j in range(len(r.index)):
                if q['Date'][i] == r['Date'][j]:
                    k = k+1
                else:
                    k = k
            if k == 1:
                pass
            if k == 0:
                q = q.drop([i])`enter code here`
```

Comment: ```q.drop``` takes an index value as arg, which is not necessarily an integer index. Try q.drop(q.index[i]). Also, there is no need for k, simply do ```if q['Date'][i] == r['Date'][j]: continue``` and ```else: q = q.drop(q.index[i])```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Use `set.intersecton()` :

```
s = set(b1.index)
for b in [b2,b3,b4,b5]:
    s=s.intersection(set(b.index))
for b in [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5]:
    b=b.drop(b.index[-b.index.isin(s)],inplace=True)
```

Comment: It kind of works, but, I want to make it to have the same index for every index. For example, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 need to have 2014-07-30 in index #5, 2014-07-31 in #6.

Comment: Could you provide example input and desired output?

Comment: Can you please help me? if you give me your email or something, I will give you my data. Actually, the code below works well, but, It returns 'empty' DataFrame, not knowing why.

Comment: @SeongNohYoon Why don't you just write what went wrong when you tried this solution, instead of asking three different people for email support?

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the dates that are present in all datasets.

This can easily be done by performing an inner join on all of them using [the `pandas.merge()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

```
b = b1.merge(on='Date', right=b2, how='inner', suffixes=['', '_b2'])
b = b.merge(on='Date', right=b3, how='inner', suffixes=['', '_b3'])
b = b.merge(on='Date', right=b4, how='inner', suffixes=['', '_b4'])
b = b.merge(on='Date', right=b5, how='inner', suffixes=['_b1', '_b5'])
```

I am making some assumptions about your data here since you did not post any example data yet.

If I got anything wrong about your data, please let me know and I will correct my example.

Example:

```
b1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2015-05-05', '2015-05-10'), 'Value':range(1,7)})
        Date  Value
0 2015-05-05      1
1 2015-05-06      2
2 2015-05-07      3
3 2015-05-08      4
4 2015-05-09      5
5 2015-05-10      6

b2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2015-05-07', '2015-05-12'), 'Value':range(4,10)})
        Date  Value
0 2015-05-05      1
1 2015-05-06      2
2 2015-05-07      3
3 2015-05-08      4
4 2015-05-09      5
5 2015-05-10      6

b = b1.merge(on='Date', right=b2, how='inner', suffixes=['_b1', '_b2'])
        Date  Value_b1  Value_b2
0 2015-05-07         3         4
1 2015-05-08         4         5
2 2015-05-09         5         6
3 2015-05-10         6         7
```

Comment: Can you please help me? if you give me your email or something, I will give you my data. Actually, the code below works well, but, It returns 'empty' DataFrame, not knowing why.

Comment: @SeongNohYoon Why don't you just write what went wrong when you tried this solution, instead of asking three different people for email support?

Comment: First of all, is there 'right' argument in join function?

Comment: @SeongNohYoon, sorry, syntax error from my side. It is supposed to be the merge function, not the join function. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

From [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns) you can see an answer

```
merged_mlist = reduce(lambda left,right: pandas.merge(left,right,on='Date', how='inner'), mlist)
```

I believe the reason your code is failing is because you are not resetting the index after dropping. I think if you want to do this manually, you can do something like store the indices first and then drop all at once

```
inds_to_drop = []
for i in range(len(b2)):
    for j in range(len(b1)):
        if b2['Date'][i] != b1['Date'][j]:
            inds_to_drop.append(i)
b2.drop( b2.index[inds_to_drop], inplace=True)    
b2.reset_index( drop=True,inplace=True) # this may or may not be necessary, havent thought all the way through
```

Better yet, if you still want to implement your for loop

```
inds_to_drop = [ i for i,dt in enumerate(b2.Date) if not pandas.np.where( b1.Date==dt)[0].size ]
```

You can do that for each iteration.. Though it is just easier to run the [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function paired with [`pandas.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Can you please help me? if you give me your email or something, I will give you my data. Actually, the code below works well, but, It returns 'empty' DataFrame, not knowing why.

Comment: @SeongNohYoon Why don't you just write what went wrong when you tried this solution, instead of asking three different people for email support?

Comment: what is the bad_inds..?

Comment: there might have been a typo in that portion of the code.. I edited it.. bad_inds was supposed to be ```inds_to_drop```.. but really I think you should try the first part: ```reduce(lambda left,right: pandas.merge(left,right,on='Date', how='inner'), mlist)``` where ```mlist=(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)```