# Merging dataframes by file name

Tags: pandas, merge

I have multiple files with the following naming convention.

```
ENCSR000EQO_0_0.txt
ENCSR000DIA_0_0.txt
ENCSR000DIA_1_1.txt
ENCSR000DIA_2_1.txt
ENCSR000DIM_0_0.txt
ENCSR000DIM_1_1.txt
ENCSR000AIB_0_0.txt
ENCSR000AIB_1_1.txt
ENCSR000AIB_2_1.txt
ENCSR000AIB_3_1.txt
```

I want to merge them as dataframes using pandas according to the file name, so I would have 4 resulting dataframes. And then for each of these 4, I want to groupby the gene(GeneName) column. Since the same gene will appear multiple times.

They all have the same columns in the same order. I can merge all 10 together at once, but I couldn't figure it out how to merge by name.

```
path = '/renamed/'

print os.listdir(path)

df_merge = None
for fname in os.listdir(path):
    if fname.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(path + fname, sep='\t', header=0)
        df.columns = ['ID ', 'Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Strand', 'Peak Score', 'Focus Ratio/Region Size', 
                     'Ann', 'DetAnn', 'Distance', 'PromoterID', 'EID', 
                     'Unigene', 'Refseq', 'Ensembl', 'GeneName', 'GeneAlias', 
                     'GeneDescription', 'GeneType']
        df = df.groupby('GeneName').agg(np.mean)
        print df
```

Thank you for any input.

Comment: I think you want something called a `join`.  Look up `pd.merge`.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something more like this, where you can use `glob` to get the filenames, check each one, and then group the concatenated results.

```
import glob
path = 'renamed'

df_merge = None
for fid in ('EQO', 'DIA', 'DIM', 'AIB'):
    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
        if fid in fname:
            df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t', header=0)
            df.columns = ['ID ', 'Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Strand', 'Peak Score', 'Focus Ratio/Region Size', 
                         'Ann', 'DetAnn', 'Distance', 'PromoterID', 'EID', 
                         'Unigene', 'Refseq', 'Ensembl', 'GeneName', 'GeneAlias', 
                         'GeneDescription', 'GeneType']
            df_ = pd.concat((df_, df))
    df_ = df_.groupby('GeneName').agg(np.mean)
    print df_
```

Edit: expanding answer to be more automated.

Based on your filenames you might be able to id them as follows:

```
import numpy as np
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))
fids = np.unique([file.split('_')[0] for file in files])
```

Putting it all together the updated code would be this:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
path = 'renamed'

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))
fids = np.unique([file.split('_')[0] for file in files])

df_merge = None
for fid in fids:
    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    for fname in files:
        if fid in fname:
            df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t', header=0)
            df.columns = ['ID ', 'Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Strand', 'Peak Score', 'Focus Ratio/Region Size', 
                         'Ann', 'DetAnn', 'Distance', 'PromoterID', 'EID', 
                         'Unigene', 'Refseq', 'Ensembl', 'GeneName', 'GeneAlias', 
                         'GeneDescription', 'GeneType']
            df_ = pd.concat((df_, df))
    df_ = df_.groupby('GeneName').agg(np.mean)
    print df_
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with glob. It seems like an interesting possibility, but in this case I  actually have 100000 files and a lot of file name variation.

Comment: Glob will still be helpful and it's part of the standard library. Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: for performance, it's often beneficial to store all of the DFs in a list and postpone calling `concat` until the end.

Comment: Indeed It worked really well. Specially performance wise. It's already done! I'm amazed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the file name as column, append all df's to a list and concat them, then group:

```
df_merge = []
for fname in os.listdir(path):
if fname.endswith('.txt'):
    df = pd.read_csv(path + fname, sep='\t', header=0)
    df.columns = ['ID ', 'Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Strand', 'Peak     Score', 'Focus Ratio/Region Size', 
                 'Ann', 'DetAnn', 'Distance', 'PromoterID', 'EID', 
                 'Unigene', 'Refseq', 'Ensembl', 'GeneName', 'GeneAlias', 
                 'GeneDescription', 'GeneType']
    df['fname'] = [fname.split('_')[0] for x in df.index] #just to multiple by length 
    df_merge.append(df)

df_all = pd.concat(df_merge)

for fn in set(df_all['fname'].values):    
    print df_all[df_all['fname']==fn].groupby('GeneName').agg(np.mean)
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. Why did I never thought of that? hehe But it takes a lot of my computer.