# Merging three large dataframes pandas have to kill program

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 3 fairly sizable dataframes that I am trying to merge in Python. I found the following technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns):

```
df1.merge(df2,on='name').merge(df3,on='name')
```

When I tried to use this on my dataframes I did not receive any errors, however each time I tried to run it I had to kill the program because PyCharm would freeze up. Is it possible that my dataframes are simply too large to merge? I have no problems merging 2 at a time so I can't imagine that that's the case, but I don't know. I really need to analyze the three together so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: what happens when you run directly your program and not run it through pycharm?

Comment: What is does the dataframe look like?

Comment: @Boud I don't really know what you mean/how to do that. Do you mean to run it through terminal?

Comment: @BobBaxley  a merging of two of the frames yields one that is [190431 rows x 12 columns]. Or are you looking for some other info?

Comment: as an alternative you can try this: `pd.concat([df1.set_index('name'), df2.set_index('name'), df3.set_index('name')], axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: @mildlyillogical yes through terminal, normal python.exe yourprogram.py

Comment: The other relevant pieces of info are: how big is df3? and how many repeated `name` values are there?  This will tell you how big you can expect your output to be.

Comment: So I realized that part of the problem was that I was trying to merge the whole dataframes when what I really needed to do was to merge them after I grouped them by 'name'. But now I'm trying to merge just two of the new aggregate multidimensional frames and getting an error telling me that the 'name' I grouped by is not a valid key

Comment: @mildlyillogical, please provide a sample (3-5 rows) input data sets and desired (output) data set