# How to merge multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-analysis

I have different dataframes and need to merge them together based on the date column. If I only had two dataframes, I could use `df1.merge(df2, on='date')`, to do it with three dataframes, I use `df1.merge(df2.merge(df3, on='date'), on='date')`, however it becomes really complex and unreadable to do it with multiple dataframes.

All dataframes have one column in common -`date`, but they don't have the same number of rows nor columns and I only need those rows in which each date is common to every dataframe.

So, I'm trying to write a recursion function that returns a dataframe with all data but it didn't work. How should I merge multiple dataframes then?

I tried different ways and got errors like `out of range`, `keyerror 0/1/2/3` and `can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'NoneType'>`.

This is the script I wrote:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3] # list of dataframes

def mergefiles(dfs, countfiles, i=0):
    if i == (countfiles - 2): # it gets to the second to last and merges it with the last
        return
    
    dfm = dfs[i].merge(mergefiles(dfs[i+1], countfiles, i=i+1), on='date')
    return dfm

print(mergefiles(dfs, len(dfs)))
```

An example:
df_1:

```
May 19, 2017;1,200.00;0.1%
May 18, 2017;1,100.00;0.1%
May 17, 2017;1,000.00;0.1%
May 15, 2017;1,901.00;0.1%
```

df_2:

```
May 20, 2017;2,200.00;1000000;0.2%
May 18, 2017;2,100.00;1590000;0.2%
May 16, 2017;2,000.00;1230000;0.2%
May 15, 2017;2,902.00;1000000;0.2%
```

df_3:

```
May 21, 2017;3,200.00;2000000;0.3%
May 17, 2017;3,100.00;2590000;0.3%
May 16, 2017;3,000.00;2230000;0.3%
May 15, 2017;3,903.00;2000000;0.3%
```

Expected merge result:

```
May 15, 2017;  1,901.00;0.1%;  2,902.00;1000000;0.2%;   3,903.00;2000000;0.3%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)

Answer (score 323, accepted):

## Short answer

```py
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['DATE'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

## Long answer

Below, is the most clean, comprehensible way of merging multiple dataframe if complex queries aren't involved.

Just simply merge with **DATE** as the index and merge using **OUTER** method (to get all the data).

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.read_table('file1.csv', sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_table('file2.csv', sep=',')
df3 = pd.read_table('file3.csv', sep=',')
```

Now, basically load all the files you have as data frame into a list. And, then merge the files using `merge` or `reduce` function.

```
# compile the list of dataframes you want to merge
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]
```

**Note: you can add as many data-frames inside the above list.** This is the good part about this method. No complex queries involved.

To keep the values that belong to the same date you need to merge it on the `DATE`

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['DATE'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)

# if you want to fill the values that don't exist in the lines of merged dataframe simply fill with required strings as

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['DATE'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('void')
```

- Now, the output will the values from the same date on the same lines.
- You can fill the non existing data from different frames for different columns using fillna().

Then write the merged data to the csv file if desired.

```
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df_merged, 'merged.txt', sep=',', na_rep='.', index=False)
```

This should give you

`DATE    VALUE1    VALUE2    VALUE3 ....`

Comment: what if the join columns are different, does this work? should we go with pd.merge incase the join columns are different?

Comment: Just a little note: If you're on python3 you need to import reduce from functools

Comment: In addition to what @NicolasMartinez mentioned: 
`from functools import reduce # only in Python 3`

Answer (score 63):

Looks like the data has the same columns, so you can:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: Bu what if you dont have the same columns?

Comment: Nice. If have same column to merge on we can use it.

Comment: concat can auto join by index, so if you have same columns ,set them to index @Gerard

Answer (score 42):

***functools.reduce*** and ***pd.concat*** are good solutions but in term of execution time pd.concat is the best.

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
nan_value = 0

# solution 1 (fast)
result_1 = pd.concat(dfs, join='outer', axis=1).fillna(nan_value)

# solution 2
result_2 = reduce(lambda df_left,df_right: pd.merge(df_left, df_right, 
                                              left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                                              how='outer'), 
                  dfs).fillna(nan_value)
```

Comment: do you use `on=...`?

Comment: @Ismail Hachimi But `pd.concat` cannot left merge. So for people who want to left merge multiple dataframes `functools.reduce` is the best way to go

Comment: result_1 is the fastest and joins on the index

Answer (score 19):

There are 2 solutions for this, but it return all columns separately:

```
import functools

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df_final = functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='date'), dfs)
print (df_final)
          date     a_x   b_x       a_y      b_y   c_x         a        b   c_y
0  May 15,2017  900.00  0.2%  1,900.00  1000000  0.2%  2,900.00  2000000  0.2%

k = np.arange(len(dfs)).astype(str)
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('date') for x in dfs], axis=1, join='inner', keys=k)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
                0_a   0_b       1_a      1_b   1_c       2_a      2_b   2_c
date                                                                       
May 15,2017  900.00  0.2%  1,900.00  1000000  0.2%  2,900.00  2000000  0.2%
```

Answer (score 19):

Another way to combine: `functools.reduce`

From documentation:

> *For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable.*

So:

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='some_common_column_name'), dfs)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [dataframe.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this

```
df = df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)
```

UPDATE

Comparing performance of this method to the currently accepted answer

```
import timeit

setup = '''import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 'May 19, 2017', 1: 'May 18, 2017', 2: 'May 17, 2017', 3: 'May 15, 2017'}, 'a': {0: '1,200.00', 1: '1,100.00', 2: '1,000.00', 3: '1,901.00'}, 'b': {0: '0.1%', 1: '0.1%', 2: '0.1%', 3: '0.1%'}})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 'May 20, 2017', 1: 'May 18, 2017', 2: 'May 16, 2017', 3: 'May 15, 2017'}, 'a': {0: '2,200.00', 1: '2,100.00', 2: '2,000.00', 3: '2,902.00'}, 'b': {0: 1000000, 1: 1590000, 2: 1230000, 3: 1000000}, 'c': {0: '0.2%', 1: '0.2%', 2: '0.2%', 3: '0.2%'}})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 'May 21, 2017', 1: 'May 17, 2017', 2: 'May 16, 2017', 3: 'May 15, 2017'}, 'a': {0: '3,200.00', 1: '3,100.00', 2: '3,000.00', 3: '3,903.00'}, 'b': {0: 2000000, 1: 2590000, 2: 2230000, 3: 2000000}, 'c': {0: '0.3%', 1: '0.3%', 2: '0.3%', 3: '0.3%'}})
dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]'''


#methods from currently accepted answer
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['date'], how='outer'), dfs)", number=1000)
3.3471919000148773
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['date'], how='outer'), dfs).fillna('void')", number=1000)
4.079146400094032

#method demonstrated in this answer
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="df = df_1.merge(df_2, on='date').merge(df_3, on='date')", number=1000)
2.7787032001651824
```

Comment: It looks almost too simple to work. But it does. How does it compare, performance-wise to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Harm just checked the performance comparison and updated my answer with the results

Comment: Oh wow, it's simpler AND faster

Answer (score 5):

@dannyeuu's answer is correct. pd.concat naturally does a join on index columns, if you set the axis option to 1. The default is an outer join, but you can specify inner join too. Here is an example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,5], 'b':[2,3,4,1,6,6,5,2,4,2], 'val': [1,4,4,3,6,4,3,6,5,7], 'val2': [2,4,1,6,4,2,8,6,3,9]})
x.set_index(['a','b'], inplace=True)
x.sort_index(inplace=True)

y = x.__deepcopy__()
y.loc[(14,14),:] = [3,1]
y['other']=range(0,11)

y.sort_values('val', inplace=True)

z = x.__deepcopy__()
z.loc[(15,15),:] = [3,4]
z['another']=range(0,22,2)
z.sort_values('val2',inplace=True)


pd.concat([x,y,z],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at this [pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)

```
filenames = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4',....]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=index_col) for filename in filenames)]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help **@jezrael**, **@zipa** and **@everestial007**, both answers are what I need. If I wanted to make a recursive, this would also work as intended:

```
def mergefiles(dfs=[], on=''):
    """Merge a list of files based on one column"""
    if len(dfs) == 1:
         return "List only have one element."

    elif len(dfs) == 2:
        df1 = dfs[0]
        df2 = dfs[1]
        df = df1.merge(df2, on=on)
        return df

    # Merge the first and second datafranes into new dataframe
    df1 = dfs[0]
    df2 = dfs[1]
    df = dfs[0].merge(dfs[1], on=on)

    # Create new list with merged dataframe
    dfl = []
    dfl.append(df)

    # Join lists
    dfl = dfl + dfs[2:] 
    dfm = mergefiles(dfl, on)
    return dfm
```

Answer (score 1):

@everestial007 's solution worked for me. This is how I improved it for my use case, which is to have the columns of each different df with a different suffix so I can more easily differentiate between the dfs in the final merged dataframe.

```py
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
suffixes = [f"_{i}" for i in range(len(dfs))]
# add suffixes to each df
dfs = [dfs[i].add_suffix(suffixes[i]) for i in range(len(dfs))]
# remove suffix from the merging column
dfs = [dfs[i].rename(columns={f"date{suffixes[i]}":"date"}) for i in range(len(dfs))]
# merge
dfs = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='outer', on='date'), dfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case and solved w/ below. Basically captured the the first df in the list, and then looped through the reminder and merged them where the result of the merge would replace the previous.

Edit: I was dealing w/ pretty small dataframes - unsure how this approach would scale to larger datasets. #caveatemptor

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = [df1,df2,df3, ...dfn]
# grab first dataframe
all_merged = df_list[0]
# loop through all but first data frame
for to_merge in df_list[1:]:
    # result of merge replaces first or previously
    # merged data frame w/ all previous fields
    all_merged = pd.merge(
        left=all_merged
        ,right=to_merge
        ,how='inner'
        ,on=['some_fld_across_all']
        )

# can easily have this logic live in a function
def merge_mult_dfs(df_list):
    all_merged = df_list[0]
    for to_merge in df_list[1:]:
        all_merged = pd.merge(
            left=all_merged
            ,right=to_merge
            ,how='inner'
            ,on=['some_fld_across_all']
            )
    return all_merged
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering by common date this will return it:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
checker = dfs[-1]
check = set(checker.loc[:, 0])

for df in dfs[:-1]:
    check = check.intersection(set(df.loc[:, 0]))

print(checker[checker.loc[:, 0].isin(check)])
```

Comment: but in this way it can only get the result for 3 files. What if I try with 4 files? Do I need to do: `set(df1.loc[:, 0].intersection(set(df3.loc[:, 0]).intersection(set(df2.loc[:, 0])).intersection(set(df1.loc[:, 0])))`?

Comment: @VascoFerreira I edited the code to match that situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me the index is ignored without explicit instruction. Example:

```
    > x = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,2], 'b':[4,5,5]})
    > x
        a   b
    0   1   4
    1   2   5
    2   2   5

    > x.drop_duplicates()
        a   b
    0   1   4
    1   2   5
```

( duplicated lines removed despite different index)