# pandas merge and update multiple dataframes into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes with index as date and a price column. I want to merge three dataframes into one and merge price column. I tried merge right as suggested by this post [Python: pandas merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes) but the result is same as concatenation with axis =1.

```
chained_price = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index = True,
                                                    how='right'), product_list)
```

product_list is a list with three df.

```
             price
date                
2013-09-10  1.000000
2013-09-11  1.011578
2013-09-12 -1.006452

            price
date               
2013-09-11  3.011578
2013-09-12  5.006452
2013-09-13  6.000544

            price
date               
2013-09-12  8.011578
2013-09-13  7.006452
2013-09-14  10.000544
```

expected result:

```
            price
date
2013-09-10  1.000000
2013-09-11  3.011578
2013-09-12  8.011578
2013-09-13  7.006452
2013-09-14  10.000544
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

You need concat with drop duplicates i.e

```
df4 = pd.concat(product_list).drop_duplicates('date',keep='last')
```

```
         date      price
0  2013-09-10   1.000000
0  2013-09-11   3.011578
0  2013-09-12   8.011578
1  2013-09-13   7.006452
2  2013-09-14  10.000544
```

If date is index then

```
df4 = pd.concat(product_list)
df4[~df4.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```