# DataFrame.combine to Combine Multiple Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying use pandas `DataFrame.combine` to combine multiple data frames. However, I couldn't figure out how to fulfill the [`func`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) parameter. The doc is not very clear to me. The documentation specifies:

```
DataFrame.combine(other, func, fill_value=None, overwrite=True)
other : DataFrame
func : function. Function that takes two series as inputs and return a Series or a scalar
fill_value : scalar value
overwrite : boolean, default True. If True then overwrite values for common keys in the calling frame
```

After some research, I found out that a similar command, `DataFrame.combine_first` can be used with `reduce` as below to combine multiple data frames ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338256/4338329)):

`reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(left,right), [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])`

How can I use `DataFrame.combine` to combine multiple data frames?

Comment: `func` param takes two `Series` as input(The two `Series` that you want to merge), and return combines series. You can also apply a combine critera or filter rows/columns using `func` param

Comment: You can only add two dataframe at a time with Dataframe.combine method. Can you describe what problem you are trying to solve by providing sample dataframes and expected output

Comment: @SahilDahiya That's not entirely true. A similar command `DataFrame.combine_first` can combine more than 2 data frames, as the link I posted shown.

Comment: @GarbageCollector How can I skip the param `func`? I don't need further criteria just simply use `combine`.

Comment: You cannot skip `func` param. If you just want to combine multiple dataframes without any condition, have a look at [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: @GarbageCollector I have tried all `concat`, `append`, `merge`, `join`. Only `combine_first` in the link I pasted achieved my goal. However, I would like to use the original `combine` but no luck on `func`. Is it possible to pass on a dull function (like 1==1) just to fulfill the param?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you can use `Dataframe.combine` to *Add two DataFrame objects and do not propagate NaN values*. 
*If for a (column, time) one frame is missing a value, it will default to the other frame’s value (which might be NaN as well)*.

`func` is a function where you write your logic to choose the value.
I think you have confusion because of lambda expression. Let me rewrite the example given in documentation without using lambda expression.

```
def _fn(left, right):
    if left.sum() < right.sum():
        return left
    else
        return right

df1 = DataFrame({'A': [0, 0], 'B': [4, 4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 3]})
df1.combine(df2, _fn)
```

**Output :**

```
    A  B

0  0  3

1  0  3
```

**P.S :**  Since OP wants to use `Dataframe.combine` to replicate behavior of `Dataframe.combine_first`, I am pasting the source code of `Dataframe.combine_first` from pandas github repository. 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L4153

```
def combine_first(self, other):
    import pandas.core.computation.expressions as expressions

    def combiner(x, y, needs_i8_conversion=False):
        x_values = x.values if hasattr(x, 'values') else x
        y_values = y.values if hasattr(y, 'values') else y
        if needs_i8_conversion:
            mask = isna(x)
            x_values = x_values.view('i8')
            y_values = y_values.view('i8')
        else:
            mask = isna(x_values)

        return expressions.where(mask, y_values, x_values)

    return self.combine(other, combiner, overwrite=False)
```

Comment: Tony, if you check out the link I pasted above, a similar command `DataFrame.combine_first` can combine more than 2 data frames. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338256/4338329. I really want to achieve a similar thing with `combine`.

Comment: That example is for merging dataframes. Merging and combine are slightly different, I guess.

Comment: When I replace `merge` with `combine_first`, it worked perfectly. So I just need to know how to make it work for `combine`.

Comment: Why don't you stick with combine_first, if that is working for you?  Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the source code of `combine_first`. Have a look.

Comment: I don't see what pasting the source code out of context can do here.

Comment: It isn't out of context. OP wants to use `combine`method. That requires a `func` argument. The implementation of `combine_first` shows how to achieve that `func`.

Comment: @Tony I would like to use the genuine method `combine`, instead of the derived one. Also, `combine_first` replace the first data frame's null values with values from the second one, which is not required. I was trying to decipher the source code. But I was not able to figure out how to compose the `func` param.