# merge multiple dataframe with specified suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I implemented to merge multiple dataframe referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes).
What I want to do is also specify the suffix for each dataframe like below.
However, I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.
I understand that giving the tuple longer than 2 for suffix is causing this problem. But I have no idea how I can write code to fix this problem.
Can anyone tell me how to write?

```
def agg_df(dfList, suffix):
    temp=reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                                             how='outer', suffixes=suffix), dfList)
    return temp

df=agg_df([df_cool, df_light, df_sp, df_hvac], ('_chiller', '_light', '_sp', '_hvac'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the suffixes before `merge`, with [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
dfs = {0: df_cool, 1: df_light, 2: df_sp, 3: df_hvac}
suffix = ('_chiller', '_light', '_sp', '_hvac')
for i in dfs:
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].add_suffix(suffix[i])
```

Then remove the `suffixes` argument from `merge` and you're done:

```
def agg_df(dfList):
    temp=reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, 
                                             left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                                             how='outer'), dfList)
    return temp

df = agg_df(dfs.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge is pyspark doesnt have suffix option but you could do it using koalas

```
    import databricks.koalas as ks

    left_kdf = ks.DataFrame(hist_sls_cy)
    right_kdf = ks.DataFrame(hist_sls_ly)
    kdf_cmbnd = left_kdf.merge(right_kdf,on=['x1','x2'],how='left',suffixes=('','_last'))
```