# How to iteratively merge dfs and increment the suffixes at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

I receive a list of csv files (that varies from 3 to 20) and I need to make an inner merge on the primary key `A` and grab all the remaining columns and put them next to each other in a consolidated single dataframe.

Since I can't share the whole csv files, I made some examples :

```
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'C': [10, 11, 12], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3], 'B': [0], 'D': [13]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 7], 'B': [9, 1], 'D': [1, 2]})

list_1 = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
list_2 = [df1, df2, df3]

merged_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='A'), list_1)
```

As you can see, the resulting dataframe should have only one row because `3` is the only primary key shared between all dataframes. But when I use the code above I got no errors with 3 dataframes but with 4, i got error :

**MergeError: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'B_x'} is not allowed.**

Here is my expected output  (`1 ROW / 8 COLUMNS`) :

I added the merge titles and the pipes just for clarify

```
       # |  MERGE 1   |   MERGE 2   |  MERGE 3
A  B_1   |   C  B_2   |  B_3   D_1  |  B_4  D_2
3    6   |  11    5   |    0    13  |    9    1
```

The duplicated columns `B and D` should have an incremented suffix like a counter.

Do you guys have any ideas to fix that ? I feel like we need to use `enumerate` inside `reduce` but I really don't know how to incorporate that. The website have suggested this [merge multiple dataframe with specified suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236438/merge-multiple-dataframe-with-specified-suffix) but I don't think it's suited for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that an intermediate merge can find matches between column names that differ from the previous merge phase. `enumerate` inside `reduce` won't help here.
We can formally add a variable suffix (by using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) for each *left* overlapped column name, and leave the *right* column as is for the subsequent merge. 
Then, collect counts for column names (without suffixes) that were overlapped multiple times. 
That counts are then used for the consecutive suffix increment on the columns of the final merged dataframe:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import count

...
lst = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

sfx_cnt = count(1)
merged_df = reduce(lambda left, right:
                   pd.merge(left, right, on='A',
                            suffixes=(f'_{next(sfx_cnt)}', '')), lst)

col_counts = merged_df.columns.str[0].value_counts()
col_counts = {k: iter(range(1, v + 1))
              for k, v in col_counts[col_counts > 1].items()}

merged_df.columns = [f'{c}_{next(col_counts[c])}'
                     if c in col_counts else c
                     for c in merged_df.columns.str[0]]

print(merged_df)
```

---

```
   A  B_1   C  B_2  B_3  D_1  B_4  D_2
0  3    6  11    5    0   13    9    1
```