# why is using loops to merge tables causing 0 values?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, merge

Using a for-loop to merge dataframes is causing the resultant dataframe to be produced with a lot of values missing which were originally present.

the problem is not the outer merge.

## example code

```
tables = c,d,e,f,g,h,............
df_all=pd.merge(a,b,how="outer")
for t in tables:df_all=pd.merge(df_all,t,how="outer")
```

lot of values from certain dataframes are missing.

Comment: You should provide at least a minimal reproducible example...

Comment: Is it possible to share the tables? It would make it easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a newbie so I cannot comment on the original question. I think the problem is that you're misusing the built-in function. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338256/4533283) that I think may solve the issue you're having as well.