# pandas - append new row with a different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append, row

I have a dataframe (df_original) that looks like this:

```
Year | Thing1 | Thing2
2010 |  748   |   461
2011 |  246   |   493
2012 |  394   |   731
```

I need to occassionally append new data. Sometimes, I get data that will have the same number of headers. Sometimes, I won't. I also cannot count on the order of the headers being the same.

Appending something like the following would be fine:

```
Year | Thing1 | Thing2
2013 |  561   |  197
```

However, I could also receive this instead, a new thing (df_new):

```
Year | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3
2013 |  561   |   197  |   369
```

**Edit: I could also receive this dataframe to append, will concat account for headers in a different order?**

```
Year | Thing1 | Thing3 | Thing2
2013 |  561   |   369  |   197
```

The desired output is the following:

```
Year | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3
2010 |  748   |  461   |   0
2011 |  246   |  493   |   0
2012 |  394   |  731   |   0
2013 |  561   |  197   |  369
```

How can I achieve this result?

I thought `pd.concat([df_original, df_new], join = 'outer', axis = 1, sort = False)` might do it because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes) but it puts the new data to the right of the original data in df_original.

Comment: Change axis=1 to axis=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply chain `pd.concat` with `fillna(0)`:

```
pd.concat([df, df_new], sort=False).fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
   Year  Thing1  Thing2  Thing3
0  2010     748     461     0.0
1  2011     246     493     0.0
2  2012     394     731     0.0
0  2013     561     197   369.0
```

If you want to reset the index, use `ignore_index`:

```
pd.concat([df, df_new], sort=False, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

**output**

```
   Year  Thing1  Thing2  Thing3
0  2010     748     461     0.0
1  2011     246     493     0.0
2  2012     394     731     0.0
3  2013     561     197   369.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A concat should do the trick. But you want axis 0, which is default, to add rows rather than columns, and to ignore the index values.

`df = pd.concat([df_original, df_new], sort=False, ignore_index=True)`

This will put Nan's instead of 0's as you have above, but you can replace those if you want.