# Using Pandas to merge many dataframes on a single column while preserving the "on" column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes inn the following format:

```
time, 2019-01-25
07:00-07:30, 180.22
07:30-08:00, 119.12
08:00-08:30, 11.94
08:30-09:00, 41.62
09:00-09:30, 28.69
09:30-10:00, 119.77
...
```

(I have many files like the above loaded into dataframes array called `frames`).

And I am using **Pandas** to merge them with the code:

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['time'],
                                                    how='outer'), frames).fillna('0.0').set_index('time')
```

(the code initially came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes))

The merge technically works, however, the final merged dataframe omits the `time` column. **Does anyone know how to perform the merge as above while still keeping the `time` column in `df_merged`?**

Comment: time, seem, turns into the  index. add `.reset_index()` at the end

Comment: @splash58 That did it! Put it in an answer and I'll accept.  Scott Boston - your answer is also great for a performance addition.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) instead of `merge` in this situation.

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[*'ABCDE'], 'B':np.random.randint(0,10,5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[*'ABCDE'], 'C':np.random.randint(0,100,5)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[*'ABCDE'], 'D':np.random.randint(0,1000,5)})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[*'ABCDE'], 'E':np.random.randint(0,10000,5)})


result1 = reduce(lambda l,r: pd.merge(l,r), [df1,df2,df3,df4])
result2 = df1.set_index('A').join([d.set_index('A') for d in [df2,df3,df4]]).reset_index()


all(result1 == result2)

True
```

Output(result1):

```
   A  B   C    D     E
0  A  7  19  980  8635
1  B  7  44  528   431
2  C  5   4  572  9405
3  D  7   7   96  2596
4  E  1   6  514   940
```

Timings:

```
%%timeit
result1 = reduce(lambda l,r: pd.merge(l,r), [df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

> 9.37 ms ± 325 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
result2 = df1.set_index('A').join([d.set_index('A') for d in [df2,df3,df4]]).reset_index()
```

> 4.04 ms ± 79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)