# Merge 3 or more dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'am trying to merge 3 dataframes by index however so far unsuccessfully.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

#identifying csvs

x='/home/'
csvpaths = ("Data1.csv", "Data2.csv", "Data3.csv")
dfs = list()   # an empty list

#creating dataframes based on number of csvs

for i in range (len(csvpaths)):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(str(x)+ csvpaths[i],index_col=0))
print(dfs[1])

#creating suffix for each dataframe's columns
S=[]

for y in csvpaths:
    s=str(y).split('.csv')[0]
    S.append(s)
print(S)



#merging attempt
dfx = lambda a,b: pd.merge(a,b,on='SHIP_ID',suffixes=(S)), dfs

print(dfx)
print(dfx.columns)
```

if i try to export it as csv i get an error as follows(similar error when i try to print dfx.columns):
'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

the output i want is merger of the 3 dataframes as follows(with respective suffixes), please help.

[Note:table below is very simplified,original table consists of dozens of columns and thousands of rows, hence require practical merging method]

[image]

Comment: Try reduce: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338256/4416883

Comment: I tried it. Details above. Any other options

Comment: kindly share input data and expected output

Comment: dfx = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=None,
                                            how='outer',), dfs)    this only works on 2 dataframes , not 3

Comment: any ideas? sorry im unable to share input data. output data i shared as above. Each dataframe consist of one column and iam merging by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
for s,el in zip(suffixes, dfs):
    el.columns=[str(col)+s for col in el.columns]

dfx=pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False, axis=1)
```

For the test case I used:

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs=[pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,7], "y": list("ghi")}), pd.DataFrame({"x": [5,6], "z": [4,4]}), pd.DataFrame({"x": list("acgjksd")})]

suffixes=["_1", "_2", "_3"]

for s,el in zip(suffixes, dfs):
    el.columns=[str(col)+s for col in el.columns]

>>> pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False, axis=1)

   x_1  y_1  x_2  z_2 x_3
0  1.0    g  5.0  4.0   a
1  2.0    h  6.0  4.0   c
2  7.0    i  NaN  NaN   g
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   j
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   k
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   s
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   d
```

---

**Edit**:

```py
for s,el in zip(suffixes, dfs):
    el.columns=[str(col)+s for col in el.columns]
    el.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

dfx=pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=False, sort=False, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: The suffix bit worked. However regarding merging of data frames didn't work cause my index is a serial number and not identical  for each data. Is there a way around it using merge or functools/reduce methods

Comment: Yes, try now - just `ignore_index=True` and `sort=False`

Comment: Hi, it didnt work. instead i created an initial merged dataframe for first 2 dfs, and then created a for loop for the remaining dfs (in the example above i have 3dfs, but im creating a code that has to deal with 3 or more),as follows:  df=pd.merge(dfs[0],dfs[1] , on='ID', how='outer')
L=0
for i in range(len(dfs)-2):
    L=L+1
    
    df=pd.merge(df,dfs[L+1], on='ID', how='outer')

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit overkill, so you essentially want to do full outer join for all dataframes within an array, right? `ID` being a key? I think my **Edit** should do the trick then

Comment: yes, however,the data iam working with does not have equal rows for each dataframe,hence that might be reason for the error

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't matter really, what error are you getting? Also - have you tried the edit part (at the end of my answer)?

Comment: this is the error: raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5331, 277), indices imply (5327, 277)

Comment: Doesn't sound like error from `pd.concat(...)` isn't this something with `pd.read_csv(...)` (not super familiar with using it, so I can just speculate, but maybe there are some unhandled empty lines, I would try to debug it first, by e.g printing every df, before you append it)

Comment: Ya i have tried the pd.concat on a more simplified list of dataframes and its working fine. not sure why im getting the error on the larger/more complex dfs might be due to reason u suggested. ill look into and see .