# Merge of 4 dataframes within groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 4 df's:

```
df1
   a  b
1  0  3
2  1  4
```

```
df2
   a  b
1  0  5
2  0  6
3  1  7
```

```
df3
   a  b
1  0  2
2  1  6  
3  1  5
```

```
...
```

Within groups of 'a' I want to merge all 4 df's on a and keep all values by putting them in a further column. The merge of df1 and df2 should look like:

```
   a  b1 b2
1  0  3  5
2  0  3  6
3  1  4  7
```

Merge of df1, df2, df3:

```
   a  b1 b2 b3
1  0  3  5  2
2  0  3  6  2
3  1  4  7  6
4  1  4  7  5
```

I tried:

```
df1.assign(dummy=1).merge(df2.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy', how='outer').drop('dummy', axis=1)
```

but this is ignoring the groups and 'a' disappears.

Comment: This is not a Cartesian product in a strict sense and you haven't done enough to explain the logic.

Comment: ok, better now?

Comment: Please see: [Python: pandas merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Cartesian product, but a simple merge across multiple dataframes.

Try this:

```
In [846]: df1.merge(df2, on='a').merge(df3, on='a').rename(columns={'b_x':'b1', 'b_y':'b2', 'b':'b3'})

Out[846]: 
   a  b1  b2  b3
0  0   3   5   2
1  0   3   6   2
2  1   4   7   6
3  1   4   7   5
```

**OR, if your dataframes can increase you can do this:**

```
In [851]: from functools import reduce    
In [852]: reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on='a'), [df1, df2, df3])    
Out[852]: 
   a  b_x  b_y  b
0  0    3    5  2
1  0    3    6  2
2  1    4    7  6
3  1    4    7  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `b` column name before merging, then use `reduce` to expand to an arbitrary number of dataframes.

```
from functools import reduce    

dfs =  [df.rename(columns={'b':f'b{num+1}'}) for num, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3])]

reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y), dfs)
```

Note that by default, `pd.merge` on shared columns, hence `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join):

First set the index of each dataframe to 'a', you can use list comprehension to do this in place like this.

```
[i.set_index('a', inplace=True) for i in [df1, df2, df3]]
```

Next, use `join`:

```
df1.join([df2, df3])
```

Output:

```
   a  b_x  b_y  b
0  0    3    5  2
1  0    3    6  2
2  1    4    7  6
3  1    4    7  5
```