# Merge many data frames over a common column without discarding different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have many data frames containing information about airports organized by day.

- One data frame will have 500 airports
- another will have 498 airports of the same names minus 2
- another will have 505 airports of the same names plus 5

etcetera.

I want to merge all the data frames

- so that the total number of airports will be labeled in individual
  rows
- the columns will be the data for each airport organized by day
- if there is no data for an airport on a given day, I want it to say
  NAN

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can you provide every head of your data frame and expecting data frame?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html might help

Answer (score 0):

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['airports'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

ref:-[Python: pandas merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes)

Example:

```
data={"Airport":["RPi-1",
"RPi-2",
"RPi-3",
"RPi-4"]}
data2={"Airport":["RPi-1",
"RPi-2",
"RPi-3",
"RPi-5"]}
data3={"Airport":["RPi-1",
"RPi-2",
"RPi-3",
"RPi-6"]}

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

from functools import reduce

data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Airport'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

Output:

```
Airport
0   RPi-1
1   RPi-2
2   RPi-3
3   RPi-4
4   RPi-5
5   RPi-6
```

Note if you want to preserve date in your case if you have day column

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Day'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```