# `pd.concat` with `join=='inner'` doesn't produce intersection of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set-intersection

I am trying to extract common rows from several dataframes using pd.concat:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = np.random.random(size=(5, 3))
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(x[1:3])
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame(x[2:4])
>>> df1
          0         1         2
0  0.257662  0.453542  0.805230
1  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994
2  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
3  0.447546  0.964252  0.163247
4  0.187212  0.973557  0.871090
>>> df2
          0         1         2
0  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994
1  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
>>> df3
          0         1         2
0  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
1  0.447546  0.964252  0.163247
```

As you can see, only the row `0.452379  0.470137  0.965709` is common to all three dataframes. To extract it, I tried:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], join='inner')
          0         1         2
0  0.257662  0.453542  0.805230
1  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994
2  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
3  0.447546  0.964252  0.163247
4  0.187212  0.973557  0.871090
0  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994
1  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
0  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
1  0.447546  0.964252  0.163247
```

Thus, `join==inner` doesn't seem to work! I should also point out that `ignore_index=True` has no effect on the behavior. In [an article](https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/) on Real Python, using `axis=1` is suggested. However, it is wrong in my opinion:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], join='inner', axis=1)
          0         1         2         0         1         2         0         1         2
0  0.257662  0.453542  0.805230  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
1  0.060493  0.463148  0.715994  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709  0.447546  0.964252  0.163247
```

What is wrong with what I am doing? Also, how would I extract common rows from several dataframes if this way doesn't work? I am using Pandas version 0.25.3.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @U11-Forward : A dataframe with the common rows only.

Answer (score 2):

In short, go with `reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=cols), dfs)`,
(see Method #2 - make sure to include `from functools import reduce`), but please see an explanation for `pd.concat` (Method #1):

**Method #1** (`concat`): I think the most dynamic, robust `pd.concat` way (of the ways I've tried with `concat` specifically) is to use. The only major benefit of this solution over the second method below is that you don't have to use an additional library; however, I think you could also write similar code with `merge` without having to use another library:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
cols = [*df1.columns]                              # enclosing with [*] is the same as tolist()
for df in dfs:
    df.set_index(cols, inplace=True)               # can only use inplace when looping through dfs (at least using my simpler method)
pd.concat(dfs, join='inner', axis=1).reset_index() # see below paragraph for explanation
Out[1]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
```

Please note that `join='inner'` means you are joining on the `index` NOT the unique rows. Also, `join` only matters if you pass `axis=1`, which is why effectively nothing happens.

---

**Method #2**: ([`merge` with `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338256/6366770)):

@Anky pointed out that `how='inner'` is default with `merge`. This was actually the first answer I posted, but I got confused about expected output and went full circle. Please see the simplest answer below:

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
cols = [*df1.columns]
reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=cols), dfs)
Out[2]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.452379  0.470137  0.965709
```

Comment: I can try this, however this looks quite complicated. My simple question is "Why doesn't pd.concat with join='inner' work?".

Comment: @Peaceful there are two reasons. See the first paragraph of my updated answer. I also show you how it would work to get the desired output doing it your way.

Comment: @Peaceful I think I have provided the two elegant methods you are looking for. If you want to do it with concat, then you must have a "common" index. Happy Holidays!

Comment: Thanks @anky Good point on mentioning the default. I will update my answer and credit you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to look for common rows:

```
temp = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
temp[temp.duplicated()]
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution to this, however.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the expected output, but I don't believe this is correct. I think the expected output is one row: `0  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=[col1, col2, col3])
```

Comment: I know this but I don't want this. For this to work, I must know how many frames I want to merge in advance. I would like to pass a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# add extral tag column
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for i, dfi in enumerate(df_list):
    dfi['tag'] = i + 1

# merge DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)

# find the duplicates rows
cols = df.columns[:-1].tolist()
cond = df[cols].duplicated(keep=False)
obj = df[cond].groupby(cols)['tag'].agg(tuple)

# filter 
cond = obj.map(len) == len(df_list)
obj[cond]
```

`obj` example:

```
# 0         1         2       
# 0.148080  0.837398  0.565498       (1, 3)
# 0.572673  0.256735  0.620923    (1, 2, 3)
# 0.822542  0.856137  0.645639       (1, 2)
# Name: tag, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar fashion to what @Ajay A said,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.random(size=(5, 3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x[1:3])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x[2:4])
```

Then,

```
df1
Out[22]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.845894  0.530659  0.629198
1  0.697229  0.225557  0.314540
2  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109
3  0.069966  0.961317  0.352933
4  0.176633  0.663602  0.235032

df2
Out[23]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.697229  0.225557  0.314540
1  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109

df3
Out[24]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109
1  0.069966  0.961317  0.352933
```

Then you can use `pd.merge` with `how='inner'`

```
pd.merge(df2, df3, how='inner')
Out[25]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109
```

or if what you are looking for is soing the intersection of the three,

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner'), df3, how='inner')
Out[26]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.972633  0.685077  0.191109
```

---

Use a `for loop` to handle a `df_list`.

```py
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_intersection = df1
for df in df_list[1:]:
    df_intersection = pd.merge(df_intersection, df, how='inner')
```

Comment: I can't accept solutions that use pd.merge. I know that this works very well, but my problem is that I don't know in advance how many dataframes I will having on which intersection is to be performed. That's the reason I am using pd.concat which accepts a list of dataframes.

Comment: @Peaceful Maybe you can use a `for loop` to do that job: `df_list = [df1, df2, df3];
df_intersection = df1;
for df in df_list[1:]:
    df_intersection = pd.merge(df_intersection, df, how='inner')`

Comment: @Ferris : Thanks! This is actually a clever workaround. Probably you should write this as an answer.