# How to combine multiple dataframes in pandas with a single unifying Date column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 datasets with similar dates. Have extracted the data range need for the columns from the extracted datasource. Want to have the four countries: Denmark, Norway, Sweden, and Finland have a single Date column.

Am able to get the panda data frames to print out invidually with their corresponding Date column and Country, but I want a single unifying column that corresponds with all four countries.

Here is what prints out, when I run the panda df head method:

```
           DATE    DENMARK
1563 2021-01-02 -65.261383
1564 2021-01-03 -60.405405
1565 2021-01-04 -69.371429
1566 2021-01-05 -73.690932
1567 2021-01-06 -76.257310
           DATE    FINLAND
1883 2021-01-02 -75.416667
1884 2021-01-03 -77.408056
1885 2021-01-04 -75.598086
1886 2021-01-05 -79.251701
1887 2021-01-06 -80.445151
           DATE     NORWAY
4603 2021-01-02 -39.164087
4604 2021-01-03 -31.763620
4605 2021-01-04 -34.002770
4606 2021-01-05 -33.815689
4607 2021-01-06 -43.454791
           DATE     SWEDEN
5883 2021-01-02 -65.853659
5884 2021-01-03 -66.385669
5885 2021-01-04 -70.704467
5886 2021-01-05 -73.450509
5887 2021-01-06 -80.805484
```

And here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import json
import math
import datetime
from jinja2 import Template, Environment

from datetime import date 


r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJ6CvZ_mgtjdrUyo3h2dU3YvWOahbYvPHpGLgovyhtI/gviz/tq?usp=sharing&tqx=reqId%3A0output=jspn')

data = r.content

data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8').split("(", 1)[1].rsplit(")", 1)[0])

d = [[i['c'][0]['v'], i['c'][2]['f'], (i['c'][5]['v'])*100 ] for i in data['table']['rows']]


df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Country', 'Date', '% vs 2019 (Daily)'])


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)


# EXTRACTING BETWEEN TWO DATES

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-02-02', "%Y-%m-%d").date()

pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D')

df = df[(df['Date'] > pd.Timestamp(startdate).floor('D')) & (df['Date'] <= pd.Timestamp(enddate).floor('D'))]


Den = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Denmark']

Fin = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Finland']

Swe = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Sweden']

Nor = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Norway']


Den_data = Den.loc[: , "% vs 2019 (Daily)"]
Den_date = Den.loc[: , "Date"]

Nor_data = Nor.loc[: , "% vs 2019 (Daily)"]
Nor_date = Nor.loc[: , "Date"]

Fin_data = Fin.loc[: , "% vs 2019 (Daily)"]
Fin_date = Fin.loc[: , "Date"]

Swe_data = Swe.loc[: , "% vs 2019 (Daily)"]
Swe_date = Swe.loc[: , "Date"]


df1 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['DATE'] = Den_date
df1['DENMARK'] = Den_data


df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['DATE'] = Fin_date
df2['FINLAND'] = Fin_data

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['DATE'] = Nor_date
df3['NORWAY'] = Nor_data

df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df4['DATE'] = Swe_date
df4['SWEDEN'] = Swe_data


print(df1.head())
print(df2.head())
print(df3.head())
print(df4.head())
```

Is it possible to unify the date to a single date column that corresponds to each country?

On the order of this:

```
DATE       | DENMARK | FINLAND | SWEDEN | NORWAY
------------------------------------------------
2021-01-01 | 43.4    | 55.6    | 75.4   | 34.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: pandas merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes)

Comment: @Boskosnitch WOW yes! This is exactly it! Pardon me for not finding it. Will do a better search in the future. Hey, what's your method for searching so I don't make this mistake in the future?

Comment: Hey no worries! Being able to effectively search for information is pretty dependent upon knowing the correct vernacular for those scenarios / operations, and that knowledge will come with time and exposure. In this instance, you were simply trying to merge some dataframes, but you just didn't know it was called merging. As you read tutorials and stuff like that, just make mental notes of the verbage used and try your best to replicate that when searching. Good luck my dude!