# Iterate over a list of dataframes and extract each dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes:

```py
list_of_dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
```

I can extract each dataframe from this list using:

```py
print(list_of_dfs['df1'].head())
```

However, I am interested in the following:

1. I want to extract these dataframes in a for loop, perform some calculations
2. Append the updated dataframes

Comment: > Append the updated dataframes. 
Append them to **what**?

Comment: Isn't this a simple for loop: `for df in list_of_dfs: do something`?

Comment: Generally iterating over rows/columns in an individual dataframe is considered a bad idea, since it's not particularly fast. Also, calculations generally should be done on individual series or dataframes themselves (although there are numerous exceptions). So, a clearer idea of what you want to do would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. My goal is to extract each dataframe from this list of dataframes, modify the dataframe by adding a few columns and then concat all these 3 dataframes into one single dataframe. Hope this help and thanks again for your help.

Comment: A general good idea is to do it in all a single step using `pandas.merge`. If you need faster performance, a few solutions exist. You can always do a computation, add a series to the dataframe as a column, and then merge it with another dataframe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to loop through the list of dataframes and use the `.apply()` method.
`some_function` is a reference to a function you define elsewhere that expects a Pandas Series object. An alternative could be to use a lambda if it's really simple

i.e. `df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda row: (your return here), axis=1)`

```
list_of_dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
for df in list_of_dfs:
    df["new_column"] = df.apply(some_function, axis=1)

dfs_combined = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```