# Merging multiple data frames causing duplicate column names

Tags: pandas

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes) suggested to use `reduce` to merge multiple data frames at once.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
df3= pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
df4= pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

from functools import reduce
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['key'], how='outer'), df_list )
```

The `merge` is executed, but there is a warning

```
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'value_x'} in the result is deprecated and will raise a MergeError in a future version.
```

and `df_meged` has columns with exactly duplicated names.
How do I force  distinct names for each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
s = pd.concat([x.set_index('key') for x in df_list],axis = 1,keys=range(len(df_list)))
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
s = s.reset_index()
s
Out[236]: 
  key   value_0   value_1   value_2   value_3
0   A -1.957968       NaN -0.852135 -0.976960
1   B  1.545932 -0.276838       NaN  0.197615
2   C -2.149727       NaN -0.364382  0.349993
3   D  0.524990 -0.476655       NaN       NaN
4   E       NaN -2.135870  0.798782       NaN
5   F       NaN  1.456544 -0.255705  0.447279
```

Answer (score 1):

An outer join in this scenario is tantamount to appending on the zero axis. You therefore are better of using the two columns in the dfs as the join keys. code below

```
from functools import reduce
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['key', 'value'], how='outer'), df_list )
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I need to keep the columns separated. Also, in my real situation, there are more columns in each data frames. I think BENY's solution is generic covering that situation.