# Conecting DataFrame in pandas by column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 Data Frames:

first:

| Country | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 6.4 |
| Albania | 7.3 |

sec:

| Country | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 610 |
| Algeria | 983 |

last:

| Country | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1 |
| Angola | 2 |

And I want to connect them by col "Country" and fill the empty values with np.nan
to get:

| Country | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 6.4 | 601 | 1 |
| Albania | 7.3 | NaN | NaN |
| Algeria | NaN | 983 | NaN |
| Angola | NaN | NaN | 2 |

Comment: Do u see the table correctly?

Comment: Don't worry I fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: pandas merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/python-pandas-merge-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with type outer for this.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

#create dataframes
df1= pd.DataFrame([["Afghanistan", 6.4], ["Albania", 7.4]], columns=['Country', 'col1'])
df2= pd.DataFrame([["Afghanistan", 610], ["Algeria", 983]], columns=['Country', 'col2'])
df3= pd.DataFrame([["Afghanistan", 1], ["Angola", 2]], columns=['Country', 'col3'])

#merge them all on Country
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Country'],
                                            how='outer'), [df1, df2, df3])
```

```
       Country  col1   col2  col3
0  Afghanistan   6.4  610.0   1.0
1      Albania   7.4    NaN   NaN
2      Algeria   NaN  983.0   NaN
3       Angola   NaN    NaN   2.0
```