# Merging three data frames with common column

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have three data frames:

```
df1:
   title   link   address  
0  A       A1      A2
1  B       B1      B2
2  C       C1      C2

df2:
    title    image
0    A        A3
1    A        A33
2    B        B3
3    B        B33
4    B        B34

df3:
    title     plan
0     A        A5
1     A        A55
2     A        A555
3     B        B5
4     B        B55
5     C        C5
6     C        C55

desired df:
     title     link      address     image     plan
0       A       A1      A2            A3        A5
1       A       A1      A2            A3        A55
2       A       A1      A2            A3        A555
3       A       A1      A2            A33        A5
4       A       A1      A2            A33       A55
5       A       A1      A2            A33       A555
```

------rest of the data like

How can I get desired df?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/how-to-merge-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Merge these Thee DataFrame Into One you can use `merge()` Function from Pandas!

Details Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data frames
data1 = {'title': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
         'link': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
         'address': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2']}

data2 = {'title': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         'image': ['A3', 'A33', 'B3', 'B33', 'B34']}

data3 = {'title': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
         'plan': ['A5', 'A55', 'A555', 'B5', 'B55', 'C5', 'C55']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# Merge data frames on the 'title' column
merged_df = pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='title'), df3, on='title')

# Reorder the columns in the desired order
desired_df = merged_df[['title', 'link', 'address', 'image', 'plan']]

print(desired_df)
```

Output:

```
   title link address image  plan

0      A   A1      A2    A3    A5
1      A   A1      A2    A3   A55
2      A   A1      A2    A3  A555
3      A   A1      A2   A33    A5
4      A   A1      A2   A33   A55
5      A   A1      A2   A33  A555
6      B   B1      B2    B3    B5
7      B   B1      B2    B3   B55
8      B   B1      B2   B33    B5
9      B   B1      B2   B33   B55
10     B   B1      B2   B34    B5
11     B   B1      B2   B34   B55
```

**Does that answer your question? if not please add more details to this question.**

[image: df merge]