# bypass pandas concate error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 3 dataframes including the information from the same group, now I'm trying to `concate` these dataframes by their group, by `set_index` as the group name, but because `df1` contains indices that are not unique, hence I'm not able to `concate` them. Is there any way to bypass that?

samples of inputs df:

```
df1:
group     A       B
 cat      1       0 
 cat      2       7
 cat      5       5
 dog      0.4     1
 dog      2       4
 dog      8       7 
 seal     7       5
 seal     1       8
 seal     7       9

df2:
group     C       D
 cat      1       3
 seal     0       5    
 dog      3       4

df3:
group     E       F
 cat      1       5
 dog      0       3 
 seal     5       9
```

wanted ouputs:

```
group     A       B       C        D       E      F
 cat      1       0       1        3       1      5
 cat      2       7       1        3       1      5
 cat      5       5       1        3       1      5
 dog      0.4     1       3        4       0      3
 dog      2       4       3        4       0      3
 dog      8       7       3        4       0      3 
 seal     7       5       0        5       5      9
 seal     1       8       0        5       5      9
 seal     7       9       0        5       5      9
```

my code:

```
 df1 = pd.read(file).set_index('group')
 df2 = pd.read(file).set_index('group')
 df3 = pd.read(file).set_index('group')

 all_data = pd.concate(df1, df2, df3, axis = 1).reset_index()
```

error:

```
 pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of `df2` and `df3` first if same sizes and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df2.set_index('group'), df3.set_index('group')], axis = 1)
all_data = df1.join(df, on='group')
print (all_data)
  group    A  B  C  D  E  F
0   cat  1.0  0  1  3  1  5
1   cat  2.0  7  1  3  1  5
2   cat  5.0  5  1  3  1  5
3   dog  0.4  1  3  4  0  3
4   dog  2.0  4  3  4  0  3
5   dog  8.0  7  3  4  0  3
6  seal  7.0  5  0  5  5  9
7  seal  1.0  8  0  5  5  9
8  seal  7.0  9  0  5  5  9
```

Also is possible use parameter `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) instead [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.read(file)
df2 = pd.read(file, index_col='group')
df3 = pd.read(file, index_col='group')

df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis = 1)
all_data = df1.join(df, on='group')
```

Comment: thanks! This is a good way to do it for a small number of dataframes. But what if a large number of dataframes and may require `concate` and `join` for many times, do you think that is there any way to `concate` all together at the same time and bypass this `unique value` error? Thanks!!

Comment: I think `concat` works with multiple dataframes perfectly and if need multiple join is possible use similar approach with `merge(how='left')` by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931/2901002) answer.

Comment: thx, the post is helpful! I actually prefer `merge`, because `join` seems have requirement of common values at the same index position. And I didn't see the difference between `merge` and `join` so far... Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!