# Finding common elements between multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, intersection, series

Hope you could help me. I am new to python and pandas, so please bear with me. I am trying to find the common word between three data frames and I am using Jupiter Notebook.

Just for example:

```
df1=
A
dog
cat
cow 
duck
snake

df2=
A
pig
snail
bird
dog

df3=
A
eagle
dog 
snail
monkey
```

There is only one column in all data frames that is A. I would like to find

1. the common word among all columns
2. the words that are unique to their own columns and not in common.

Example:

duck is unique to df1, snail is unique to df2 and monkey is unique to df3.

I am using the below code to some use but not getting what I want straightforward,

```
df1[df1['A'].isin(df2['A']) & (df2['A']) & (df3['A'])]
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong. Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you need to *chain* multiple `isin` calls. What's worse is that you'd need to keep track of which dataframe is the largest, and you call `isin` on *that* one. Otherwise, it doesn't work.

To make things easy, you can use `np.intersect1d`:

```
>>> np.intersect1d(df3.A, np.intersect1d(df1.A, df2.A))
array(['dog'], dtype=object)
```

---

Similar method using `functools.reduce` + `intersect1d` [by piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556169/finding-common-names-between-three-data-frames-pandas/46556372?noredirect=1#comment80066766_46556372):

```
>>> from functools import reduce # python 3 only
>>> reduce(np.intersect1d, [df1.A, df2.A, df3.A])
array(['dog'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `reduce(np.intersect1d, [df1.A, df2.A, df3.A])`

Comment: hi coldspeed, it works!! thanks for that. I would like to ask you the same question I have asked above. How to get the output without quotes or commas? many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: thanks for helping. Finally managed to figure it temporarily. Just converted the list into a data frame and that looks neat. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: does this still work if the dataframes have different length values?

Answer (score 23):

Simplest way is to use `set` intersection

```
list(set(df1.A) & set(df2.A) & set(df3.A))

['dog']
```

---

However if you have a long list of these things, I'd use `reduce` from `functools`.  This same technique can be used with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's use of `np.intersect1d` as well.

```
from functools import reduce

list(reduce(set.intersection, map(set, [df1.A, df2.A, df3.A])))

['dog']
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your inout. Yes, it does work however when I get the output they all come within single quotes separated by commas. Is it possible to retrieve them as a clean list. Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `how='inner'` keyword parameter in `pd.merge`.

For example,

```py
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]

import functools as ft
df_common = ft.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='A', how='inner'), dfs)
```

References:

- [How to find the common elements in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-find-the-common-elements-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)