# CSV value mapping from 2 files like map in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, mapping

I have two csv files that i created with python from an unstructured data but i don't want my script to output two files once i run the script on a json. So lets say i have a file A with columns as follows:

File 1:

```
feats   ID     A         B     C       E
AA      123   3343      234   2342    112
BB      121   3342      237   2642    213``
CC      122   3341      232   2352    912
DD      123   3343      233   5342    12
EE      121   3345      235   2442    2112
```

...and so on with lets say, 10000 rows of different values and 6 columns. Now I want to check these values of column "ID" against file 2 and merge on the values of ID.

File 2:

```
Char_Name           ID    Cosmic Awareness            
  Uatu              123          3.4              
  Galan             121          4.5              ``
  Norrin Radd       122          1.6              
  Shalla-bal        124          0.3              
  Nova              125          1.2
```

This file 2 has only 5 rows for 5 different values for b and lets say 23 
column values. I can do this easily with map or apply in pandas but i'm 
dealing with 1000's of files and don't wanna do that. Is their any way 
like mapping the file 2 values (name and cosmic awareness columns) to File 1 by adding new columns titled 'name' and 'cosmic' (from file 2) by matching the values with corresponding ID values on File 1 and File 2. The expected output should be somewhat like this.

Final File:

```
feats   ID     A         B     C       E      Char_Name    Cosmic Awareness
AA      123   3343      234   2342    112     Uatu           3.4
BB      121   3342      237   2642    213``   Galan          4.5
CC      122   3341      232   2352    912     Norrin Radd    1.6
DD      123   3343      233   5342    12      Uatu           3.4
EE      121   3345      235   2442    2112    Galan          4.5
```

Thanks in advance and if their is any way to improve this question, the suggestions are welcome. I will incorporate them here. I have added the expected outcome above.

Comment: Can you add sample of 2,3 files like 1000s and expected output?

Comment: Jezrael I have added the expected output that i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931) ?

Comment: It may work but again the problem is going the pandas way... I don't want to do that and work with formatting the csv in the initial phase itself. So any way with which we can read 2 files, do something similar to map/merge based on id will really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `glob` for all file names and then in list comprehension create `DataFrame`:

```
from functools import reduce
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files]
```

Last `merge` together:

```
df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ID'), dfs)
```

For `outer` join is possible use `concat`:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['ID']) for fp in files]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```