# How to merge two dataframes based on two different columns that could be in reverse order in certain rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I am looking for a way to merge two dataframe based on two columns containing ids that could be considered as `id1, id2` pair or `id2, id1` pair.

I found a similar question to what I am looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521066/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-a-pair-of-columns-in-multiple-pandas-dataframes) but it doesn't help me with getting the output I need.

I am working with two dataframes `df` and `temp` and each of them have two columns with ids in them:

```py
df:
    time    level_0   level_1
0   60.0    id1       id2
1   420.0   id2       id3
2   120.0   id3       id4
3   336.0   id4       id5

temp:
    number  level_0   level_1  length  width
0   0       id1       id2      25      2
1   1       id4       id5      56      3
2   2       id4       id3      12      7
3   3       id2       id3      750     2
```

I would like to merge them to get a `final` dataframe with `level_0` and `level_1` with `time`, `number`, `length` and `width`.

As you can see in `temp` two of the ids are reversed in row 2 and that doesn't allow me to merge both dataframe successfully and I get `None` values in the selected columns.
Also the accepted answer of the post quoted above doesn't seem to work as I get a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'` error.

Is there a way of doing a merge based on two columns knowing that some of their values could be in reverse order?

Edit:
After reading @SoheilPourbafrani comment, I tried using sets to compare `level_0` and `level_1` in both dataframes. However, I came across the fact that rows in `temp` are not in the same order as in `df` and don't allow me to compare rows between one another.

Here's the desired output for better understanding:

```py
    time    level_0   level_1 number length  width
0   60.0    id1       id2     0      25      2
1   420.0   id2       id3     3      750     2
2   120.0   id3       id4     2      12      7
3   336.0   id4       id5     1      56      3
```

Comment: Based on my understanding you want to join `df` and `temp` based on the column list: `[level_0, level_1]` and the issue is you only care about their value, no matter in what order they are. If that's the case add a new column to both dataframes (use `withColumn` method) by a function that map columns `level_0` and `level_1` to a unique value, regardress the order. For example if `(id1, id2) -> 1`, so `(id2, id1) -> 1`. Finally join them based on the new column.

Comment: Thank you for your input @SoheilPourbafrani! I tried maping that unique value while using sets but I came across a slight problem. Turns out rows of ```temp``` and ```df``` are not in the same order and I cannot merge the two of them.

Comment: Could you add your desire output to the question so I can have a better understanding of it?

Comment: Yes of course, I just did @SoheilPourbafrani.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comment, you need to add a join column to the DataFrames such that satisfy your business logic and then simply join them.

### Spark Dataframe

Here we have a function that gets the value of the `level_0` and `level_1` columns as input and generates a unique string:

```
def generateJoinIdCol(col1, col2):
     col1Num = int(col1[-1])
     col2Num = int(col2[-1])
     if col1Num <= col2Num:
             return col1 + ':' + col2
     else:
             return col2 + ':' + col1
```

Next, we declare the method as Spark UDF function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
udfGenerateJoinIdCol = F.udf(generateJoinIdCol, StringType())
```

After that we add the new `id` column to the `df` and `temp`:

```
dfWithIdCol = df.withColumn('id', udfGenerateJoinIdCol('level_0', 'level_1'))
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| time|level_0|level_1|     id|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 60.0|    id1|    id2|id1:id2|
|420.0|    id2|    id3|id2:id3|
|120.0|    id3|    id4|id3:id4|
|336.0|    id4|    id5|id4:id5|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+

tempWithIdCol = temp.withColumn('id', udfGenerateJoinIdCol('level_0', 'level_1'))
+------+-------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|number|level_0|level_1|length|width|     id|
+------+-------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|     0|    id1|    id2|    25|    2|id1:id2|
|     1|    id4|    id5|    56|    3|id4:id5|
|     2|    id4|    id3|    12|    7|id3:id4|
|     3|    id2|    id3|   750|    2|id2:id3|
+------+-------+-------+------+-----+-------+
```

Finally, we join them:

```
res = dfWithIdCol.join(tempWithIdCol.select('id', 'number', 'length', 'width'), 'id')
+-------+-----+-------+-------+------+------+-----+
|     id| time|level_0|level_1|number|length|width|
+-------+-----+-------+-------+------+------+-----+
|id3:id4|120.0|    id3|    id4|     2|    12|    7|
|id4:id5|336.0|    id4|    id5|     1|    56|    3|
|id1:id2| 60.0|    id1|    id2|     0|    25|    2|
|id2:id3|420.0|    id2|    id3|     3|   750|    2|
+-------+-----+-------+-------+------+------+-----+
```

### Update: Pandas Dataframe

I just noticed that by dataframe you meant Pandas dataframe not spark! Here is the Pandas approach:

```
import pandas as pd

""" initialize dataframes """
# df
dfData = {'time': [60.0, 420.0, 120.0, 336.0], 'level_0': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'], 'level_1': ['id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'] }
df = pd.DataFrame (dfData, columns = ['time','level_0','level_1'])

# temp 
tempData = {'number': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'level_0': ['id1', 'id4', 'id4', 'id2'], 'level_1': ['id2', 'id5', 'id3', 'id3'], 'length': [25, 56, 12, 750], 'width': [2, 3, 7, 2] }
temp = pd.DataFrame (tempData, columns = ['number','level_0','level_1', 'length', 'width'])
```

Then let's add the id column to both dataframes

```
# generate id function 
def generateJoinIdCol(col1, col2):
     col1Num = int(col1[-1])
     col2Num = int(col2[-1])
     if col1Num <= col2Num:
             return col1 + ':' + col2
     else:
             return col2 + ':' + col1

# add the id column to df
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda row: generateJoinIdCol(row.level_0, row.level_1), axis = 1)

# df
    time level_0 level_1       id
0   60.0     id1     id2  id1:id2
1  420.0     id2     id3  id2:id3
2  120.0     id3     id4  id3:id4
3  336.0     id4     id5  id4:id5


# add the id column to temp
temp['id'] = temp.apply(lambda row: generateJoinIdCol(row.level_0, row.level_1), axis = 1)

# temp
   number level_0 level_1  length  width       id
0       0     id1     id2      25      2  id1:id2
1       1     id4     id5      56      3  id4:id5
2       2     id4     id3      12      7  id3:id4
3       3     id2     id3     750      2  id2:id3
```

Finally, we just need to do an inner join on the dataframes

```
# Join
result = df.merge(temp, how = 'inner', on = 'id')[['time', 'level_0_x', 'level_1_x', 'number', 'length', 'width']]

# rename columns
result.rename(columns={'level_0_x': 'level_0', 'level_1_x': 'level_1'}, inplace=True)

# result
    time level_0 level_1  number  length  width
0   60.0     id1     id2       0      25      2
1  420.0     id2     id3       3     750      2
2  120.0     id3     id4       2      12      7
3  336.0     id4     id5       1      56      3
```

Answer (score 1):

I created my id in the apply using if else

```
 df1['id']=""
 df2['id']=""
 df1['id']=df1.apply(lambda row: row.level_1+":"+row.level_0 if row.level_0>row.level_1 else row.level_0+":"+row.level_1, axis=1 )
 df2['id']=df2.apply(lambda row: row.level_1+":"+row.level_0 if row.level_0>row.level_1 else row.level_0+":"+row.level_1, axis=1 )
 final=df1.merge(df2,on=['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I am providing is not in python but you can easily replicate that in python. I am doing it in scala/spark but you can get the idea of how you can do it.

```
//Creating the sample data
val df = Seq((60.0,"id1","id2"),(420.0,"id2","id3"),(120.0,"id3","id4"),(336.0,"id4","id5"))
.toDF("time","level_0","level_1")
val temp = Seq((0,"id1","id2",25,2),(1,"id4","id5",56,3),(2,"id4","id3",12,7),(3,"id2","id3",750,2))
.toDF("number","level_0","level_1","length","width")

//applying transformation to combine the columns based on the condition in specific order
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("index0",substring(col("level_0"), 3, 4))
.withColumn("index1",substring(col("level_1"), 3, 4))
.withColumn("level", when($"index0" <= $"index1",concat($"level_0",lit(" "),$"level_1"))
.otherwise(concat($"level_1",lit(" "),$"level_0")))
.drop("index1","index0","level_0","level_1")

val temp1 = temp.withColumn("index0",substring(col("level_0"), 3, 4))
.withColumn("index1",substring(col("level_1"), 3, 4))
.withColumn("level", when($"index0" <= $"index1",concat($"level_0",lit(" "),$"level_1"))
.otherwise(concat($"level_1",lit(" "),$"level_0")))
.drop("index1","index0","level_0","level_1")

//doing the join to get the final required output
val finalDF = df1.join(temp1,Seq("level"),"inner").withColumn("level_0", split($"level"," ")(0))
.withColumn("level_1", split($"level"," ")(1))
.drop("level").orderBy("level_0")
display(finalDF)
```

You can see the final output as below :

[image]