# Merging Dataframes on Month, Or Unlike Column & Grouping

Tags: pandas, join, indexing, merge, group-by

I have three dataframes I would like where I want to merge or join them based on the month column/field, then group by title.

df1:

```
Month Year    TotalNumberofStreams  TitleSortName
9     2018    1529                  Movie A
9     2018    368                   Movie B
1     2018    703                   Movie C
1     2018    2278                  Movie D
1     2018    382                   Movie E
```

df2:

```
Month   Year    video_view  TitleSortName   
9       2018    3           Movie A        
9       2018    6           Movie B        
3       2017    9           Movie C       
3       2017    4           Movie D        
3       2017    3           Movie E
```

df3:

```
    Month   Year    Views   TitleSortName
    9       2018    243     Movie A
    9       2018    156     Movie B
    9       2018    133     Movie C
```

Desired Output:

```
Month Year  Views  video_view  views TotalNumberofStreams TitleSortName
9     2018  NaN    NaN         NaN   1529                 Movie A
9     2018  NaN    3           NaN   NaN                  Movie A
9     2018  243    NaN         NaN   NaN                  Movie A
```

Attempts:

I tried merging based on TitleSortName, with this code here:

```
merge=df1.merge(df2, how='outer',left_on='TitleSortName',right_on='TitleSortName')
```

however this returns duplicates, and a lot of data that makes me do even more cleaning.

I also attempted to join based on month:

```
join_df = df1.join(df2.set_index('Month'),on='Month')
```

this returns `Value Error: Pandas join issue: columns overlap but no suffix specified`

Im looking through different articles online, and I see maybe I can use a for loop to iterate through the month column and save the rows to a list that are alike and return a the rows how I desire, as well as lambda join functions, for example a:

```
lambda x: "/" .join(x), based on the desired columns
```

is there an easier way to do this or any way to achieve the result i want at all?

Comment: Do you need `from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Month','Year','TitleSortName']), [df1, df2, df3])` ? If yes, then it is [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931)

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense. Why are there so many `NaN` and why only Movie A 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

Your group-by doesnt make sense. But for the merge, you can do this.

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [9, 2018, 1529,'A'],
    [9,2018, 368, 'B'],
    [1,2018, 703, 'C'],
    [1,2018,2278,'D']]),
    columns=['Month', 'Year', 'TotalNumberOfStreams','Title'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [9,2018, 3, 'A'],
    [9,2018, 6, 'B'],
    [3,2017,5, 'C']]),
    columns=['Month', 'Year', 'Video Views','Title'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [9,2018,243,'A'],
    [9,2018,156,'B']]),
    columns=['Month', 'Year', 'Total Views','Title'])


merged_df=df1.merge(df2,on=['Month','Year','Title']).merge(df3,on=['Month','Year','Title'])

merged_df
Out[32]: 
  Month  Year TotalNumberOfStreams Title Video Views Total Views
0     9  2018                 1529     A           3         243
1     9  2018                  368     B           6         156
```