# ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values

Tags: python, pandas

I should join 2 pandas DataFrames with partially overlapping column names: `Col1`,`Col2`. The other columns do not overlap.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: Index(['Col1','Col2']
```

Joining is done as follows:

```
df1.join([df2], how='inner')
```

Of course, I can manually drop `Col1` and `Col2` from one of DataFrames. But I wonder if there is a better solution. I am using pandas version `0.25`.

I am searching for something like this (or other option that would allow avoiding the manual dropping of columns):

```
df1.join([df2], how='inner', take_overlapping_columns_from_left=True)
```

Is it possible to do or should I proceed with the columns dropping solution?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the duplicate values in the index, we can tell the concat() function to ignore the index and instead use the default integer index.

something like:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using `join`?

Comment: And what if I have 4 `df's`. Can I do `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], ignore_index = True)` ?

Comment: I am not sure about multiple data frames. This link can help you to get more insights https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html. Here I found very helpful one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your comment, if you want to join multiple dfs with overlapping column names then it is best to rename those columns or use [suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join).