# How can I iterate over pandas dataframes and concatenate on another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a few files that I've read into pandas dataframes that share the same values for the `0` column, but have differing values for the `1` column.

How can I iterate over multiple dataframes, pull out just the `1` column, and add each one to the first pandas dataframe after its `1` column. Example:

**df1**

```
0     1
-10   5
-9.95 2
-9.8  3
```

**df2**

```
0     1
-10   2
-9.95 4
-9.8  7
```

**df3**

```
0     1
-10   6
-9.95 8
-9.8  5
```

**What I want as a final df (column names could be changed to 0123 or something)**

```
0     1 1 1
-10   5 2 6
-9.95 2 4 8
-9.8  3 7 5
```

I'm new to python and pandas so I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: you just need a pd.merge to merge these three DataFrames

Comment: you may want t check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146609/9840637