# Merge based on multiple columns of all excel files from a directory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say I have a dataframe `df`, and a directory `./` which has the following excel files inside:

```
path = './'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('.xls', '.xlsx')):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            # dfs.append(read_dfs(os.path.join(root, file)))
# df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.concat([left, right], axis = 0), dfs)
```

Out:

```
df1.xlsx,
df2.xlsx,
df3.xls
...
```

I want to merge `df` with all files from `path` based on common columns `date` and `city`. It works with the following code, but it's not concise enough.

So I raise a question for improving the code, thank you.

```
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on = ['date', 'city'], how='left')
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on = ['date', 'city'], how='left')
df = pd.merge(df, df3, on = ['date', 'city'], how='left')
...
```

Reference:

[pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns/30512931#30512931)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may works:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df0, df1, df2, dfN]
df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['date', 'city']), dfs)
```