# Read multi-index excel file and reshape the headers in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given an excel file `data.xlsx` as follows:

[image]

I have read it with `df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header = [0, 1], index_col = [0, 1], sheet_name = 'Sheet1')`,

Out:

```
district  2018        2019      
         price ratio price ratio
bj cy       12  0.01     6  0.02
sh hp        4  0.02     3  0.05
```

I wonder if it's possible to transform it to the following format? Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('city','district','year')).reset_index()
print (df)
  city district  year  price  ratio
0   bj       cy  2018     12   0.01
1   bj       cy  2019      6   0.02
2   sh       hp  2018      4   0.02
3   sh       hp  2019      3   0.05
```

Comment: Thank you. Did I read excel correctly? Seems `city` is missing.

Comment: You could check output of `pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header = [0, 1], index_col = [0, 1], sheet_name = 'Sheet1')` from question, no column name `city`.

Comment: @ahbon - I understand, it is only name of column like metadata. So if not in input file, cannot be parsed. So in my solution used `rename_axis` for set it.

Comment: Great, it works. Do you mind have a look this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314450/merge-based-on-multiple-columns-of-all-excel-files-from-a-directory-in-python

Comment: @ahbon - How working [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931/2901002) ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll test with it.