# Combining dataframes based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 3 dataframes

**df_hl**

```py
State   District    Level   Name    TRU No_HH   TOT_HL_P   TOT_HL_M
0   0   India   India   Total   449787  1773040 
0   0   India   India   Rural   192891  834692  
0   0   India   India   Urban   256896  938348
```

**df_sc**

```py
State   District    Level   Name    TRU   No_HH_Head_sc TOT_P_sc
0   0   India   India   Total   41694863    201378372
0   0   India   India   Rural   31803775    153850848   
0   0   India   India   Urban   9891088     47527524
```

**df_st**

```py
State   District    Level   Name    TRU   No_HH_Head_st   TOT_P_st   TOT_M_st
0   0   India   India   Total   21511528    104545716   52547215    
0   0   India   India   Rural   19302332    94083844    47263733    
0   0   India   India   Urban   2209196     10461872    5283482
```

These are the structures of the dataframes after I have preprocessed their names. There are more number of columns and rows in the original dataset.

The thing I want to do is combine all these dataframes based on the following columns : `State, District, Level, Name and TRU.

My result dataframe should be of the following form :

```py
State   District    Level   Name    TRU No_HH   TOT_HL_P   TOT_HL_M   No_HH_Head_sc  TOT_P_sc  No_HH_Head_st   TOT_P_st   TOT_M_st 
0   0   India   India   Total   449787  1773040   41694863    201378372  21511528    104545716   52547215
0   0   India   India   Rural   192891  834692   31803775    153850848 19302332    94083844    47263733  
0   0   India   India   Urban   256896  938348  41694863    201378372   2209196     10461872    5283482
```

I tried to create index based on those columns, but don't know how to combine all columns. Any help would be really appreciated.

```py
df_hl.set_index(['State', 'District', 'Level', 'Name', "TRU"], inplace=True)
df_sc.set_index(['State', 'District', 'Level', 'Name', "TRU"], inplace=True)
df_st.set_index(['State', 'District', 'Level', 'Name', "TRU"], inplace=True)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this what you are looking for:

`df1.merge(df2,how='left').merge(df3,how='left')`?

Comment: Any reason why you merged the dataframes using `how = left`

Comment: That refers to the kind of join you want : left join vs inner join vs right join so on ...

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is an inner joint of the dataframes. Assumed you have pandas imported as `import pandas as pd`:

```
df_final = pd.merge(left=pd.merge(left=df_hl, right=df_sc, on=["State", "District", "Level", "Name", "TRU"]), right=df_st, on=["State", "District", "Level", "Name", "TRU"])
```

A more generic way for doing this with an arbitrary number of dataframes is described here:

[pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)

```
import functools
dfs = [df_hl, df_sc, df_st]
df_final = functools.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left=left, right=right, on=["State", "District", "Level", "Name", "TRU"]), dfs)
```