# How to merge three different dataframe in pandas/python with mask condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge three different large data frame(1400,000 rows), two dataframe are normal, and the third dataframe are from this `mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)`
df[mask] & df['e'].eq(0)`, accoring to my below sample data,

```
a      b        c       dt                   e   h i j k
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0   ........
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       1   ........
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0   ........
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0   ........
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0   ........
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
```

Below code will get to many useless and duplicated columns, is there any way to merge three different large data?

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'dt', 'e'])
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
df['x'] = mask.astype(int)
dfs = [df1, df2, df]
df_full = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, on=['id']), dfs)
```

Comment: Not easy answering because no sample data for `df1, df2`. Also if problem is `will get to many useless and duplicated columns` is possible filter non necessary columns with `usecols` like `f1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', usecols=['need col1','need col2'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael do you know how to merge three data frame or not? if yes, you don't need my sample data of df1 and df2.

Comment: Your code for merging is good, so ask for it.

Comment: the code refers to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns

Comment: yes, code is good, problem is in data if `will get to many useless and duplicated columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add some information about the dataframes? Do they have the same columns? Or does each frame have different columns and different number of rows? I am not asking about the data itself but its structure.

Also, I'm not too sure about this, but try to include `'id'` in the columns to be read from the third dataframe, because it looks like you are trying to merge all three dataframes on that index.

```
usecols = ['id', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'dt', 'e']
```

(Edit: I tried merging without that 'id' and it didn't work for me.)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delimiter=";")
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', delimiter=";")
df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv', delimiter=";", usecols = ['id', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'dt', 'e'])

mask = (df['a'].gt(10) & df['a'].lt(25)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
df['x'] = mask.astype(int)
dfs = [df1, df2, df]

df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['id'])
df_merged = df_merged.merge(df, on=['id'])
```

I tried with my own CSV files:

- test1.csv has some columns (id, a, b, c)
- test2.csv has different columns (id, d, e, f)
- test3.csv has the same columns as in your question: (id, a, b, c, dt,
  e)

Comment: df1 and df2 have many duplicated columns, and how to remove columns of df1 and df2?

Comment: You could use `df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delimiter=";", usecols= [...])` and `df2 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delimiter=";", usecols= [...])` so you only read the columns that you want to merge (also make sure you include `'id'` in both lists)