# Pandas merge 3 dataframes with same columns

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have 3 dataframes where I have one string column which I want to merge on and 2 similar columns which I want to add up

df1:

```
index user x y
 1    john 5 6
 2    pete 10 10
```

df2:

```
index user x y
 1    john 1 1
 2    pete 2 2 
 3    nash 5 5
```

df3:

```
index user x y
 1    nash 6 7
 2    john 2 4 
 3    kyle 3 3
```

I want:
df4:

```
index user x y
 1    john 8 11
 2    pete 12 12 
 3    nash 11 12
 4    kyle 3  3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, first [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum)

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(["user"], as_index=False)[['x', 'y']].sum()
```

---

```
   user   x   y
0  john   8  11
1  kyle   3   3
2  nash  11  12
3  pete  12  12
```