# Pandas to lookup and return corresponding values from many dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A list of names and I want to retrieve each of the correspondent information in different data frames, to form a new dataframe.

I converted the list into a 1 column dataframe, then to look up its corresponding values in different dataframes.

The idea is visualized as:

[image]

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ["David","Mike","Lucy"]}

data_h = {'Name': ["David","Mike","Peter", "Lucy"],
    'Hobby': ['Music','Sports','Cooking','Reading'],
    'Member': ['Yes','Yes','Yes','No']}

data_s = {'Name': ["David","Lancy", "Mike","Lucy"],
    'Speed': [56, 42, 35, 66],
    'Location': ['East','East','West','West']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_hobby = pd.DataFrame(data_h)
df_speed = pd.DataFrame(data_s)

df['Hobby'] = df.lookup(df['Name'], df_hobby['Hobby'])

print (df)
```

But it returns the error message as:

```
ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

I have also tried:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df_hobby, on='Name')
```

It works but it includes unnecessary columns.

What will be the smart an efficient way to do such, especially when the number of to-be-looked-up dataframes are many?

Comment: you can include only necessary columns when merging : `pd.merge(df, df_hobby[['Name','Hobby']], on='Name')` , also refer to linked duplicate where you can create `dfs = [df,df_hobby[['Name','Hobby']],df_speed[['Name','Speed']]]`

Comment: correcting the above comment: `dfs = [df,df_hobby[['Name','Hobby']],df_speed[['Name','Location']]]` then `reduce(lambda x,y : pd.merge(x,y,on='Name'),dfs)`

Comment: @anky - hmmm, it should be reopened, I think.

Comment: @jezrael its same as dupe link,  except we are considering a subset of dataframe here. You can re-open if you want however , I don't agree since the duplicate link has a lot of proposed and well written answers. Appreciate that this is a well written question though

Comment: @anky - exactly it was my opinion, so linked in my answer dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter only columns for merge and columns for append like:

```
df = (pd.merge(df, df_hobby[['Name','Hobby']], on='Name')
        .merge(df_speed[['Name','Location']], on='Name'))
 
print(df)
    Name    Hobby Location
0  David    Music     East
1   Mike   Sports     West
2   Lucy  Reading     West
```

If want working with list use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns) solution with filtering columns:

```
dfList = [df,  
          df_hobby[['Name','Hobby']],
          df_speed[['Name','Location']]]

from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name'), dfList)
print (df)
    Name    Hobby Location
0  David    Music     East
1   Mike   Sports     West
2   Lucy  Reading     West
```

Comment: thank you sir! Option #1 rocks for simplicity is always the King. :) Wish you and your family a very Merry Christmas and happy new year!

Comment: @MarkK - For you too, and be safe and healthy too ;) Thank you.