# Best way to concat/merge list of pandas dataframes into one while preserving all values in a given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of pandas dataframes as below and would like to concat/merge them so that the values in the shared column are exhaustive between all of the dataframes. What is the best approach?

DF 1:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| BLAH1 | A |
| BLAH2 | Z |

DF 2:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BLAH2 | Z | B |
| BLAH3 | Q | K |

DF 3:

| Col1 | Col4 |
| --- | --- |
| BLAH2 | C |
| BLAH3 | W |

Desired Outcome

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLAH1 | A | NaN | NaN |
| BLAH2 | Z | B | C |
| BLAH3 | Q | K | W |

Comment: related: [pandas three-way joining multiple dataframes on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-three-way-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)

Answer (score 4):

If the keys are unique, within each dataframe, you can do a concat then groupby:

```
list_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
pd.concat(list_dfs).groupby('Col1').first()
```

In general, you can combine a `reduce` and `merge`:

```
from functools import reduce

# find common columns
commons = reduce(lambda x,y: set(x).intersection(set(y)), list_dfs)

reduce(lambda x,y: x.merge(y, on=commons), list_dfs)
```

Comment: Would both cases you provide handle duplicate columns between the dataframes? Apologies for not first mentioning that is also a possibility - I have updated the question.

Comment: Either way, you would need to identify the common columns first. Then replace the list in `'Col1'` place. See updated answer (second approach)

Comment: if Col1 is the common one i want to merge on, but col2 appears in multiple dataframes in the list how is that best handled? Currently i use suffixes=('', '_y') then df.drop(df.filter(regex='_y$').columns.tolist(),axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: That's gonna be difficult, you should try a sample set of data where `Col2` is only in `df2` and `df3`, and ask what do you want from that?

Comment: I want it exactly as I have shown in the edited question. Col2 should take the values in the dataframes (values across the dataframes, if duplicate columns, will be the same)

Comment: as long as the data are unique by `Col1`, first approach would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) like so :

```py
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=list(left.columns.intersection(right.columns)), how='outer'), [df1, df2, df3])
```

Here the `reduce` apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value.
The left argument, `left`, is the accumulated value and the right argument, `right`, is the update value from the iterable.

The trick here is to `merge` on the list of common columns from the DataFrames to get the expected result. @QuangHoang did something similar
and find the trick before me.

Output :

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   BLAH1   A       NaN     NaN
1   BLAH2   Z       B       C
2   BLAH3   Q       K       W
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `functools.reduce` with `pd.DataFrame.combine_first` and comprehension:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: x.combine_first(y), 
       (df.set_index('Col1') for df in [df1,df2,df3])).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  BLAH1    A  NaN  NaN
1  BLAH2    Z    B    C
2  BLAH3    Q    K    W
```

Given input dataframes as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['BLAH1', 'BLAH2'],
                   'Col2':[*'AZ']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['BLAH2', 'BLAH3'],
                   'Col2':[*'ZQ'],
                   'Col3':[*'BK']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['BLAH2', 'BLAH3'],
                    'Col4':[*'CW']})
```